# setTimeout and "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a method that uses the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function and makes a call to another method. On initial load method 2 works fine. However, after the timeout, I get an error that says `method2` is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

ex:

```
test.prototype.method = function()
{
    //method2 returns image based on the id passed
    this.method2('useSomeElement').src = "http://www.some.url";
    timeDelay = window.setTimeout(this.method, 5000);
};

test.prototype.method2 = function(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        if (document.images[i].id.indexOf(name) > 1) {
            return document.images[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just to make sure: is "finction" just a typo in the question or is it in your code also?

Comment: please add the definition and scope of method2

Comment: test.prototype.method2 = function(name) {

    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        if (document.images[i].id.indexOf(name) > 1) {
            return document.images[i];
        }
    }
};
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks crescentfresh, sorry, didn't intend to delete that 'T'

Comment: THIS in javascript is explained here https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130241/1048572)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The issue is that `setTimeout()` causes javascript to use the global scope.  Essentially, you're calling the `method()` class, but not from `this`.  Instead you're just telling `setTimeout` to use the function `method`, with no particular scope.

To fix this you can wrap the function call in another function call that references the correct variables.  It will look something like this:

```
test.protoype.method = function()
{
    var that = this;

    //method2 returns image based on the id passed
    this.method2('useSomeElement').src = "http://www.some.url";

    var callMethod = function()
    {
        that.method();
    }

    timeDelay = window.setTimeout(callMethod, 5000);
};
```

`that` can be `this` because `callMethod()` is within method's scope.

This problem becomes more complex when you need to pass parameters to the `setTimeout` method, as IE doesn't support more than two parameters to `setTimeout`.  In that case you'll need to read up on [closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html).

Also, as a sidenote, you're setting yourself up for an infinite loop, since `method()` always calls `method()`.

Comment: Hey, This works in mozilla bu not in ie! any clue? also images do not loop, stops once it reaches the last image

Comment: What an excellent article on closures with practical examples in your link! Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

A more elegant option is to append `.bind(this)` to the end of your function.  E.g.:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.foo();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^ <- fix context
```

So the answer to the OP's question could be:

```
    test.prototype.method = function()
    {
        //method2 returns image based on the id passed
        this.method2('useSomeElement').src = "http://www.some.url";
        timeDelay = window.setTimeout(this.method.bind(this), 5000);
        //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ <- fix context
    };
```

Answer (score 11):

The `this` you used in `setTimeout` is scoping via itself. Create a `var _this = this;` inside your `test.prototype.method` function and use `_this` instead.

Comment: What does "scoping via itself" mean?

Answer (score 7):

in es6 you can do it like this

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.foo();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: great simple answer

Answer (score 1):

> I get an error that says method2 is undefined

Yes, when you slice off `this.method` from its owner and pass the function alone to `setTimeout`, you lose the association that sets `this`, so `this` in `method()` is equal to the global object `window`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585840/implement-map-in-javascript-that-supports-object-methods-as-mapped-functions/585918#585918) for an explanation of the surprising way `this` actually works in JavaScript.