# Is there anyway on onmouseover to fire after mouseovering after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I want to make sure the user wants to have something pop up by mouseing over a div. I don't want the user to accidentally trigger something to pop up without intent. `setTimeout` doesn't work because even if it's very brief, the pop up will still pop up, it's just delayed. What I want is the user to mouseover something for 1sec for a pop up to display.

**update:

When I do this:

```
<div onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout('display(this)', 5000);">
```

the timer works and it is displayed after 5 seconds but `this` is not passed and I can't get the element via `$(element).next()`, etc.
When I do this:

```
 <div onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout(display(this), 5000);">
```

the timer doesn't work. What is wrong, how can I get the timer and the `this` to be passed?

Thanks!

**update2: the `this` problem from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem) states: "Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global) object, it will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout."

I found the answer to overcome this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback) where you have to "save a reference to the context where the setTimeout function call is made"

Comment: You *should* use `setTimeout`, but you should then clear it via `clearTimeout` if you no longer wish to handle the event.

Comment: Great idea! I hate it when I roll the mouse around a page and all kinds of unwanted tooltips pop up and obscure the content, and I don't want this to happen to my users.

Comment: Try to add quotas into display parameters

Comment: @DonCallisto like this: `<div onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout(display('this'), 5000);">` ? It still doesn't work, it gets into the function but `this` isn't passed the way I want it to.

Comment: @JCarter I updated my answer to call display properly with `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this should works:

```
onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout(yourFunctionName, 1000);"
```

You have also to add:

```
onmouseout="clearTimeout(myTimer);"
```

Comment: Yuk... inline Javascript _and_ code in string argument to `setTimeout`?

Comment: Won't that have the problem he mentioned?

Comment: no, that's not what i'm looking for, that still triggers the event, it just delays it.

Comment: I just edited to remove the string in setTimeout for you, this is still not a good way to do it though because it exposes `myTimer` to the global space, so it could break other scripts on the page, and, more minor in comparison IMO, you use the HTML attribute to run a script instead of a script tag.

Comment: I've tried this and updated my question, my problem now is why `this` isn't being passed to my function

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you:

```
<div id="example">Hover me</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var timer;
        var el = document.getElementById('example');

        el.onmouseover = function(){
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                display(el);
                // If display takes no arguments and uses the "this" keyword inside it
                // Use display.call(el); instead
            }, 1000);
        }

        el.onmouseout = function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

[**Example on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/PhRzN/)

Answer (score 0):

On mouse over you can start a timer. On mouse out reset the timer to 0. If the timer reaches 1s, you can trigger your event and reset the timer to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I also later came across something called the hoverIntent jQuery Plug-in, worth checking out.