# How do I change scope of "this" in setInterval and setTimeout functions

Tags: javascript, object, settimeout, setinterval

How is it possible to use `this` inside of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` calls?

I want to use it like :

```
function myObj() {
  this.func = function(args) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      this.func(args);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Some time ago I did it for `.onclick` event this way :

```
this.click = function(func) {
  this.elem.onclick = (function(func, obj) {return function(){func.apply(obj)} })(func,this);
};
```

but I don't know how I can do it for `intervals` and `timeouts`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to just save `this` into a local.  The local `self` isn't changed by the context in which `setInterval` and `setTimeout` callbacks are invoked.  It will instead maintain the original `this` value

```
function myObj() {
  var self = this;
  this.func = function(args) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      self.func(args);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In theory**, you could do continue using `this` everywhere and avoid `that`, `self` etc like this:

```
setTimeout.call(this, function() { 
  this.func(args);
}, 1000);
```

...or...

```
setTimeout.apply(this, [function() { 
  this.func(args);
}, 1000]);
```

...**but**, doing so causes the following [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846445/ns-error-xpc-bad-op-on-wn-proto-exception-in-firefox-22) in Firefox 22+:

> **NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO**: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

---

If you're using jQuery 1.4+, you can avoid this by using `jQuery.proxy()` instead of `call` or `apply`:

```
setTimeout( $.proxy(function() {
  this.func(args);
}, this), 50);
```

There is some [more detail, and alternatives using **native ECMAScript 5**, **Underscore.js** and  **prototype.js** at this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800171/568458).