# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO Exception in Firefox 22

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I maintain an addon that seems to be having issues with Firefox 22. There is a JavaScript module that uses loadFrameScript, which in turn injects some libraries using mozIJSSubScriptLoader. The file brought in by loadFrameScript looks similar to below:

```
// Create a JS sub-script loader.
var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);

// Create a context object.
var executionContext = Object.create(content);

// Load the libraries.
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://my-package/content/libs/jquery.js", executionContext);
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://my-package/content/logic.js", executionContext);
```

However, the act of loading jQuery throws an exception:

> Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object
>   Source File: chrome://my-package/content/libs/jquery.js
>   Line: 829

It does not look like jQuery is doing anything crazy on that line, just calling setTimeout. Googling around for this message, I found a similar situation in the [Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/issues/89) extension, but no resolution. I am at a loss as to what I should be doing differently, or what changes broke the way I load jQuery in Firefox 22. Is there a better way to bring in jQuery?

### Update

This really is the most aggravating problem. I dropped using the `executionContext` object, because I don't even remember why I used it in the first place, and jQuery loads into the content just dandy.

```
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://my-package/content/libs/jquery.js", content);
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://my-package/content/logic.js", content);
```

Now, however, other scripts that also get loaded into `content` cannot use `sendAsyncMessage`. I suppose this makes sense, as it's a whole new scope that does not have the addon API's, but now I am not sure how to read the page DOM. How do I load my logic and jQuery into `content` and still retain the ability to `sendAsyncMessage` results?

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents -

I'm also maintaining an extension that runs into the problem. For me, the solution is really the same as indicated in scriptish - use window.xxxx instead of directly referencing that method.

For example, previously one of the lines calls setTimeout() directly, after I changed it to window.setTimeout(), the code works.

Since you said that line is not doing anything other than calling setTimeout, I suppose it's the same issue. Try adding window. before that call.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason you did use `executionContext` in the first place was that otherwise stuff would be directly defined on `content`, which could conflict with the website, other add-ons and/or leak to the website. So better have a wrapper around window where you load your stuff.

I just coded up a minimal "content script" loader based on frame scripts. Nothing much, but should get the job done. I verified on FX 24 that jquery will work in it, and the stuff does not leak into the content window.

```
// Frame scripts share a scope, so better not mess them up ;)
(function() {
  "use strict";
  const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
  const utils = {};
  try {
    throw new Error();
  }
  catch (ex) {
    let url = ex.fileName.replace(/\/[^\/]*?$/, "/");
    const ssm = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIScriptSecurityManager);
    Object.defineProperties(utils, {
      "url": {
        enumerable: true,
        value: function(fn) {
          return url + fn;
        }
      },
      "mayLoad": {
        enumerable: true,
        value: function(o) {
          let node = (o.document || o);
          let window = (o.ownerDocument || o).defaultView || o;
          try {
            return window.location != "about:blank" &&
              !ssm.isSystemPrincipal(node.nodePrincipal);
          }
          catch (ex) {
            Cu.reportError(ex);
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
    });
    Object.freeze(utils);
  }
  try {
    const loader = Cc["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
      .getService(Ci.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);

    // Create a context object for each window that get's loaded.
    // Or use DOMWindowCreated, like the add-on manager does to install
    // the InstallTrigger.
    addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
      let window = e.target.defaultView;
      if (!utils.mayLoad(window)) {
        // Refuse to load in chrome (system) pages.
        return;
      }

      // Need to create our context in the window scope (compartment).
      // The reason to create a wrapper/context it in the first place
      // is to avoid clashes with other add-ons, the website itself,
      // etc.
      let executionContext = Cu.createObjectIn(window);
      // Wire up the window to be the prototype.
      executionContext.__proto__ = window;
      // Add some useful stuff you want the "content scripts" to have
      // access to.
      Object.defineProperties(executionContext, {
        "sendAsyncMessage": {
          enumerable: true,
          value: sendAsyncMessage.bind(null)
        },
        "reportError": {
          enumerable: true,
          value: Cu.reportError.bind(Cu)
        },
        "doSomething": {
          enumerable: true,
          value: function(arg) {
            Cu.reportError("did something " + arg);
          }
        },
        "loadScript": {
          enumerable: true,
          value: function(fn) {
            loader.loadSubScript(utils.url(fn), executionContext);
          }
        }
      });
      // Normalize the properties, i.e. move them over to the correct
      // window scope (compartment);
      Cu.makeObjectPropsNormal(executionContext);

      // Load initial scripts
      executionContext.loadScript("test.js");
    });
  }
  catch (ex) {
    content.console.error(ex);
  }
})();
```

The key points are:

- Use `Cu.createObjectIn(window)` to get the scope (compartment in Spidermonkey) right and avoid the `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO` exceptions.
- Use `Cu.makeObjectPropsNormal()`, if you define additional stuff on your context.
- Don't try to inject stuff into chrome-privileged windows (`utils.mayLoad`).
- The `throw new Error()` try-catch is just a reliable hack to get the current URI (`ex.fileName`) to later allow specifying relative paths when loading scripts.