# Calling this inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, timeout

I Am looking for a way to proper call `this` inside function now i have quick hack `var that = $(this);` but i am sure that there is propper way of doing it. How i can avoid this hack?

This is input field which i use to get var and inspect Typing Interval

```
<input type="text" data-package="pink" class="js-p-input">
```

this i my code:

```
var cCalc = (function ($) {
    var s;
    return {
        settings: {
            typingTimer: "",
            doneTypingInterval: 300,
            $inputs: $(".js-p-input"),

        },

        init: function () {
            s = this.settings;
            this.bindUIActions();
        },

        bindUIActions: function () {

            //on keyup, start the countdown
            s.$inputs.on('keyup', function () {
                var that = $(this);                
                clearTimeout(s.typingTimer);               
                s.typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    cCalc.doneTyping(that, that.data("package"));
                }, s.doneTypingInterval);
            });

            s.$inputs.on('keydown', function () {
                clearTimeout(s.typingTimer);
            });

        },


        doneTyping: function ($input, packageName) {
            console.log('done!');
            cCalc.getValues($input.val(), packageName);
        },

    };

})(jQuery);

cCalc.init();
```

Comment: it doesn't work with $(this), because you are in setTimeout, so this has changed

Comment: I think this is the right way to pass a 'this' variable to another function. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366643/how-do-i-change-scope-of-this-in-setinterval-and-settimeout-functions

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {...}.bind(this), s.doneTypingInterval);`  EDIT: but nothing is wrong with using a closure as you do in your code. Other way would be: `setTimeout(cCalc.doneTyping, s.doneTypingInterval, $(this), $(this).data("package"));` even passing `$(this).data("package")` seems redundant because inside `doneTyping()` method, you can get data without passing it as parameter: `$input.data('package')`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using that "hack", it is standard operating procedure. See also here [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply?rq=1) for even more "hacky" stuff with "this" that is standard.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there's not really anything wrong with using a closure but you could alternatively bind "this" into the timeout function scope like so:

```
s.$inputs.on('keyup', function () {

  clearTimeout(s.typingTimer);

  s.typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {

    cCalc.doneTyping($(this), $(this).data("package"));

  }.bind(this), s.doneTypingInterval);

});
```