# setInterval function can't read array

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass correct “this” context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

I have a problem with my little script.

```
function test() {
    this.arr = new Array('a','b','c');
    this.func = function() {
        //Do something with this.arr. But it's undefined.. WHY???
    }
    this.Start = function() {
        this.Interval = setInterval(this.func, 1000);
    }
}

var Test = new test();
Test.Start();
```

When I try to do anything with array in "func", it keeps telling me, that the array is undefined. Why?

Comment: why are you creating a bunch of variables? just do everything where it is needed and see if the variables are getting in the way due to `this`

Comment: You capitalisation is odd. Usually only constructors are capitalised, and all other variables (including methods) are lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the wrong `this` reference, try:

```
function Test() {
  this.arr = new Array('a','b','c');
  this.func = function() {
    console.log(this.arr);
  };
  this.start = function() {
    var fun = this.func.bind(this);
    this.interval = setInterval(fun, 1000);
  };
}

var test = new Test();
test.start();
```

This article about `this` is a really interesting if you need more information: [Function invocation and this](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/)

Also, note that I've changed the case on some symbols. Remember, functions that are meant to be used as constructors start with a uppercase letter, variables and methods use lowercase.

Comment: While I agree with the style tips, I strongly suggest you give a reference, since there is no standards body (or BDFL) for JavaScript style.

Answer (score 1):

Timers/Intervals are called on global scope so 'this' is set to 'window'. To get around this, you can pass a third option to setInterval() which will be used as a parameter for the specified function call.

```
function Test(){
    this.array = new Array('a','b','c');
    this.function = funct(){ }
    this.start = function(){
        this.Interval = setInterval(function(passedObj){
            passedObj.funct.call(passedObj);
        },1000,this);
    }
}
var testObj = new Test();
testObj.start();
```

Reading the comments below, you will see this is meant for nodejs. This, however, will not work for IE8 and/or earlier.

Comment: What is `a`? This seems very wrong.

Comment: The additional arguments to `setTimeout` aren't supported in IE8 and lower.

Comment: I couldn't think of a descriptive name for it. unless I name it passedParam, which I felt was over doing it

Comment: ...also using `function` as a property name will give you trouble in some implementations.

Comment: Uh, haven't seen the additional argument. But a simple derefencing variable would be much easier.

Comment: This is not a javascript for browser, but node.js

Comment: I meant to put 'funct', not function. cleaned up code, made mention that it isn't supported in IE8 or earlier.