# how to make setTimeout refer to context of object?

Tags: javascript, object, this, settimeout

```
var myObj = {
    name:"mike",
    go:function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }

}

myObj.go()   //logs out mike
setTimeout(this.myObj.go,200)  //logs out (emptyString)
```

Comment: @adeneo The `this` pointer would not be set that way (well, it'd reference the global object in non-strict mode).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Comment: @adeneo Totally wrong.

Comment: `this` isn't context. It's a special variable that is set by the call and can be any object (es3) or any value (es5 strict mode).

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/VT5wH/):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  myObj.go();
},200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable reffering to the object before:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {_this.myObj.go();}, 200);
```

Comment: This is the most complete solution code, though OP seems to be using `this` to reference the global context, otherwise a variable declared through `var` would hardly be assigned to a property of an object.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah the weird part is why they're referencing it with `this`, when they declare it with `var`. I think this method would be necessary if `this` was something specific to the context and was needed.

Comment: @Ian Exactly. `=]` Finished reading answers, time to spend some upvotes then.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

```
setTimeout(this.myObj.go.bind(this.myObj), 200);
```

or

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    that.myObj.go();
}, 200);
```

Note that `.bind` isn't supported in older browsers, so a polyfill may be required in order to support it. Here's some information about the method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Note that `.bind` has been introduced in ES5, therefore to support older browsers one should either use your version with a function wrapper or a [`.bind` shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, thanks for pointing it out - I didn't feel compelled enough to include that :) I'm wondering when it's going to be time that we stop pointing out when old browsers don't support certain methods. Probably never, as people will use old IE forever...

Comment: Well, guess I'm one of the few which still spends sleepless nights patching my HTML5 page to be fallbackable to IE6 (yeah really) but well, I believe there isn't much use in supporting IE<8 so I'm slowly migrating and removing old IE hacks. None from us want to restrict ourselves from using advanced HTML5/CSS3 features just because of old IE, so my methodology now is just to apply graceful degradation down to IE8 tops. And yeah, IE8 doesn't support `.bind()` and it'd generate an ugly JS error breaking script execution. `:P`

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = {
    name:"mike",
    go:function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }

}

setTimeout(function(){myObj.go()},200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myObj = {
    name:"mike",
    go:function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }

}

myObj.go();   //logs out mike
setTimeout(function(){
    myObj.go(); //logs out mike too
},200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right minus a few things.

```
setTimeout(this.myObj.go,200)
```

Should be

```
setTimeout(function() {myObj.go()},200)
```

It was undefined because `this.myObj` was not in the scope of setTimeout, nor was it wrapped in an anonymous function, or a variable function. You were on the right track though!