# Passing context to JavaScript callback

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback

I have a Cordova/PhoneGap application where I create directories on the phone persistent storage. I have a problem passing the context to the Cordova plugin API. I use the [DirectoryEntry.getDirectory()](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry_getdirectory) method who receives two callbacks - one for success and the second is for error. The success method signature is `function success(dirEntry) { ... }`, where I want to use it like this:

```
var x = // some data collected
rootdor.getDirectory("mydir",  {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail); 
// store x in the retrieved/created directory, can be done in the success method
```

I need help with the last part - how do I pass reference to `x` in the success callback.

Comment: surely with 12.5k score you can format code by now

Comment: Working on it... I'm new to JavaScript at this level (haven't used it for some time now) and besides - others can benefit too.

Comment: i meant in question...make it easier to read

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to address the correct context? Did you take a look for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback ?

Comment: @charlietfl Oops... It was too late at night I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've learned about JavaScript scopes which solves the case. The question referred by @sleepwalker was a great help.

Also if someone is interested, I suggest to have a look at the implementation of `onPhotoCaptureSuccess()` in [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/html5expense/blob/master/client/shared/www/controller.js).