# Backbone View render not being called upon Model change, although bound?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, and entirely new to Backbone.js.

In the code below, I am creating a new UserLocationModel and passing this model instance to a new UserLocationView object. In this view's `initialize()` I (try to) bound `render()` to any changes happening to the passed along model.

I'm fairly certain the model changes, I receive new latitude and longitude values from `navigator.geolocation` and I assign these values to the model's values. I also know that the view succesfully receives the model (this.model is never null).

**Why is UserLocationView.render() not being called?**

**Model:**

```
var UserLocationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        latitude: -1,
        longitude: -1
    },

    updateLocation: function() {
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.positionSuccess, this.positionFailure);
                    }
    },

    positionSuccess: function(position) {
        this.set({ 
            latitude : position.coords.latitude,
            longitude : position.coords.longitude
        });
    },

    positionFailure: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

**View:**

```
var UserLocationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this,'render');
        if(this.model) this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log('UserLocationView render called.');
        ...
    }
});
```

**Execution start:**

```
window.MyApp = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        userLocationModel = new UserLocationModel();
        userLocationView = new UserLocationView({ model: userLocationModel });
        userLocationModel.updateLocation();
        this.render();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

I have rewritten some of the code above, to include `model.set`.

**Edit 2: Additional information for moxn.**

**main.js:**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','template', 'myapp'], function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.App = new MyApp({ appendTo: $('body') });
    });
});
```

**called by this in the HTML:**

```
<script data-main="../static/js/main" src="../static/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you make the `Model` changes?

Comment: @DennisRongo The changes happen in positionSuccess().

Comment: Have you tried using:
`positionSuccess: function(position) {
        this.set({ latitude : position.coords.latitude,
        longitude : position.coords.longitude
    },...`?

Comment: @DennisRongo I have, please see the edit to my question.

Comment: @Caroline where do you call MyApp.initialize? Either directly or via `new MyApp()`

Comment: @moxn I added some code snippets for you in my question. You should know my issue is fixed though, please see my answer below. Can I help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure both Dennis' and Lyn's answers are valid as well, I just haven't been able to make them work.

What *did* work, is:

**Approach A:**

```
    updateLocation: function() {
        console.log('UserLocationModel.getLocation() called.');
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(_.bind(this.positionSuccess, this));
        }
    },

    positionSuccess: function(position) {
        this.set({ 
            latitude : position.coords.latitude,
            longitude : position.coords.longitude
        });
    },
```

**Approach B:**

```
    //in model
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,'positionSuccess');
    },
```

More specifically, I'm using underscore.js' `_.bind()` or `_.bindAll()`:

> bind() Bind a function to an object, meaning that whenever the function is called, the value of this will be the object. Optionally, bind arguments to the function to pre-fill them, also known as partial application.

Your answers have given me the understandment to go look for and find that exact answer in [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the `set` method suggested by Dennis Rongo, you need to make sure `this` is a model object when `positionSuccess` is invoked. So something like this:

```
updateLocation: function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        var self = this;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() { self.positionSuccess() },
                                                 function() { self.positionFailure() });
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Lyn, thanks to your help I found underscore.js' bind().

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrentPosition` changes the context of `this` of that of the geolocation.

Try doing something like:

```
updateLocation: function() {
        if(navigator.geolocation)
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              this.positionSuccess.call(this), 
              this.positionFailure.call(this));
    },
```

Comment: I understand. But then how do I keep access to `position` in `positionSuccess`?

Comment: The `positionSuccess` should still receive the parameter passed in by the Geolocation.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, thanks to your help I found underscore.js' bind().