# css change inside setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: jquery

The below code inside setTimeout doesn't work whereas same code without setTimeout works perfectly fine

```
var size_disabled_input = 0;

$('#txtUSLead , #txtmy').on("mouseover", function () {
size_disabled_input = $(this).css('width');
if ((this.value.length) > 8) 
{
$(this).css('cssText', 'width: ' + ((this.value.length + 1) * 7) + 'px !important');
}
});

$('#txtUSLead, #txtmy').on("mouseout", function () {
setTimeout(function (){
$(this).css('cssText', 'width: ' + size_disabled_input + 'px !important');
}, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `setTimeout` function `this` will not refer to the button that you are in.

So, you can use the `bind` method:

```js
$('#txtUSLead, #txtmy').on("mouseout", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).css('cssText', 'width: ' + size_disabled_input + 'px !important');
    }.bind(this), 2000);
})
```

Or, use a variable to store the this value:

```js
$('#txtUSLead, #txtmy').on("mouseout", function () {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.css('cssText', 'width: ' + size_disabled_input + 'px !important');
    }, 2000);
})
```

Or, you can use the `proxy()` method in jQuery:

```js
$('#txtUSLead, #txtmy').on("mouseout", function () {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).css('cssText', 'width: ' + size_disabled_input + 'px !important');
    }, this), 2000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks !!! You nailed it! I was getting this as undefined in console log but couldnt identify it referrign to window object in there

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by strict mode or normal mode ? Also the solutions you gave , it is cross compatible with all the browsers right? I used the bind method