# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when calling function withing object

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

```
var spaceship = {
fps : 10,
speed : 1,
traveled : 0,
currency : 0,
initialize : function() {
    this.update();
},
update : function() {
    this.traveled += this.speed/this.fps;
    setTimeout(this.update, 1000/this.fps);
    this.render();
},
render : function() {
    $("#spaceshipbg").attr("background-position", "0px "+this.traveled+"px");
}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
spaceship.initialize();
});
```

So this is my code, Whenever i load up the page, i get an error with the line "this.render()". I can't see the problem here, i can successfully call this.update() from the initialize function, but when i call this.render() it says it's undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `initialize` is called, it calls `this.update()`. `update()` itself works, even the first call to `this.render()`. However, `setTimeout` will invoke `update`, but it will not call it on your object. Therefore, `this` will not reference your object anymore. `this.render()` is undefined.

For more information about the problem, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/).

The solution might look like this:

```
update : function() {
    var self = this;
    this.traveled += this.speed/this.fps;
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Enforce the correct context
      self.update();
    }, 1000/this.fps);
    this.render();
},
```