# reference controller property with controller as syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do i set my `devices` property to the data returned from `/store.aspx/GetDevices`. Using `this.devices` isn't working.

```
var app = angular.module("storeApp", []);
app.controller("storeController", ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.devices = hardcodeddevices;
    $http.post("/store.aspx/GetDevices", {})
        .success(function (data) {
            //this.devices = JSON.parse(data.d);
        });

}]);

var hardcodeddevices = [...
```

Comment: like this `function (data) {
            //this.devices = JSON.parse(data.d);
        }.bind(this)`

Comment: or assign _this_ to some variable and use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Comment: used `.bind(this)`. Why dont you post it as an answer

Comment: because i sure this question duplicated :-)

Comment: it one of those questions about _this_ in javascript, that was many times answered before :-)

Comment: also possibly with angular you can do something like `this.devices = 
    $http.post("/store.aspx/GetDevices", {})
        .success(function (data) {
            return JSON.parse(data.d);
        });
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback function, `this` means the success callback function.You could assign `this` to a variable like `self`.

```
var app = angular.module("storeApp", []);
app.controller("storeController", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.devices = hardcodeddevices;
    $http.post("/store.aspx/GetDevices", {})
        .success(function (data) {
            self.devices = JSON.parse(data.d);
        });

}]);

var hardcodeddevices = [...
```

Comment: you wrong: In success callback function, `this` means `$http` object

Comment: Probably correct way is to a use angular service which handles returns data from the server and get that in your controller using DI and u can assign that to 'this' or $scope,