# Call React component method from within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to solve the following:
 I have two methods within my Component:
 getData requests the data and gets approximate time when the results will be ready.
 I want to set setTimeout for that delay and than pass the request id to method processData, which makes another request to retrieve the actual data using the request id it got from requestData I am trying to access.
I am unable to reference the processData from within setTimeout in ajax's success.
How to do that? I've tried this.processData, this.refs., processData without success.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
processData: function(id) {
 // ajax gets the data using the id (which we got from sending the request in requestData)
},
requestData: function(colid) {
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/getvalues/id/"+colid,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {this.refs.processData(data.id);}, data.estimatedWaitTime+250);
            }
});
}
});
```

Comment: your `this` is different than what you think inside your setTimeout.

Comment: I feel you should use a promise somewhere ...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the component's context (e.g. `this`), then you must `bind` the context in any callback.  Otherwise, `this` will change its meaning:

```
requestData: function(colid) {
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/getvalues/id/"+colid,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {this.refs.processData(data.id);}.bind(this), data.estimatedWaitTime+250);
            }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

For your example, in order to *tunnel* the context down to the `setTimeout` callback, you need to bind both the `ajax` callback and the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: wouldn't `setTimeout(this.refs.processData(data.id), data.estimatedWaitTime+250)` and bind only the `ajax` also work?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Not exactly, because `this.refs.processData(data.id)` won't *return* a function.  And `setTimeout` takes a function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the **this** to another local variable (say **_this**) before the setTimemout

```
success: function(data) {
   var _this = this;
   setTimeout(function() {//.....use _this here ......}, data.estimatedWaitTime+250);
}
```

Becuase inside the setTimeout **this** means **window**

Refer [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Comment: it helped. Thank you! It was the simplest solution.