# What is the value of "this" within an anonymous function in setTimeout below?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this

I've rewritten the underscore.js delay function to look like the below. It works after tinkering with using apply() but I don't fully understand what the "this" in the apply is pointing to in the anonymous function within setTimeout.

```
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
     setTimeout(function() {
       return func.apply(this, args);
     }, wait);
 };
```

Comment: It is the Global object (aka `window` in a browser).

Comment: global, depending on the JS engine. `window`, `node`, etc.

Comment: For solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Comment: @user2864740 Nice pointer.

Comment: @ВидулПетров It's a good solution question, but it doesn't really explain the mechanics of `this`..

Comment: Ahh, that is what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @user2864740 See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/1367611) answer.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to `window` inside the `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` functions.
If you want to avoid this side effect, you can "bind" the value of `this`:

```
_.delay = function(func, wait, thisArg) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
   thisArg = thisArg || this;//assume a default value
   setTimeout(function() {
     return boundFunction.apply(thisArg, args);
   }, wait);
};
```

Then you can pass what will be the value of `this` to `_.delay()` or let it be `_` by default.

Another way is to bind your function before passing it to `_.delay()`:

```
function a() {console.log(this);}
_.delay(a.bind({foo:'bar'}), 1000); //prints {foo: 'bar'}
```