# javascript callback function works just once

Tags: javascript, class, callback

i use a callback function into a object to update html (xmlhttprequest).

the firts time (onload), callback works fine.
the second time (timer1) property url is undefined under the Post function
no errors in console

my script and some console.log:

````
class PostJSON {
    constructor() {
        this.response = {};
        this.url = "../iot/PostJSON.php";
    }
    callback = function() {
    }

    Post = function(datapost,callback) {
        console.log(this.url);
        console.log(datapost);
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let myJSON = JSON.stringify(datapost);
        xhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(myJSON); 
        var instance = this;
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                instance.response = json;
                instance.callback();
            }
        }
    }
}```

const net = new PostJSON();
net.callback = function(){
    console.log(this.response["data"]["datetime"][0]);
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = this.response["data"]["temp"][0] + "°C";
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', net.Post({"id":1}) );

var myTimer1 = setInterval(net.Post, 5000,{"x":1,"id":1});
````

Comment: Make `Post` an arrow function. [What is the value of "this" within an anonymous function in setTimeout below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542764/what-is-the-value-of-this-within-an-anonymous-function-in-settimeout-below)

Comment: That's not how you use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you should pass a reference to the event handler function to the method, but you're passing `undefined` instead. Here: `net.Post({"id":1})`, but `net.Post` doesn't return anything.

Comment: i've found a solution : in class : that = this; and them i use that in function Post

Answer (score 0):

```
function PostJSON() {
    this.response = {};
    this.url = "../iot/PostJSON.php";
    this.callback = function() {
    }
    var that = this;
    this.Post = function(datapost,callback) {
        console.log(that.url);
        console.log(datapost);
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let myJSON = JSON.stringify(datapost);
        xhttp.open("POST", that.url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(myJSON); 
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                if (json.hasOwnProperty('infos'))
                    if (json["infos"].hasOwnProperty('infos'))
                        json["infos"]["infos"] = JSON.parse(json["infos"]["infos"]);
                that.response = json;
                that.callback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```