# Is a function fn passed to setTimeout invoked not as a function but as a method like window.fn()?

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout, strict

In strict mode, `this` should be `undefined` inside of a non-method (a function):

see http://jsfiddle.net/jfp06nc9/1/
showing `this` is `undefined`

However, when the `setTimeout` is used, then `this` is bound to `window`:

see http://jsfiddle.net/jfp06nc9/2/
and http://jsfiddle.net/jfp06nc9/3/
showing that `this === window` returns true.

so it looks like the function `fn` passed to `setTimeout` is invoked not as a function, but as a method, like `window.fn()` or `fn.call(window)` or `(fn.bind(window))()`.

see http://jsfiddle.net/jfp06nc9/4/
showing the last 3 calls above would all show `this === window` as `true`.

Is that true?  I can't find any specification about it so please include that in your answer.

(the jsfiddle was running in Chrome 46.0)

**P.S. This question is NOT about what `this` is bound to, but about, in non-strict mode, `setTimeout` can run `fn()` and the `this` will be bound to `window`.  But in strict mode, if `setTimeout` really runs it as `fn()`, then `this` should now be `undefined` instead of `window`, so there is a subtle difference there, that it seems `setTimeout` runs it (or arrange to run it) not as `fn()` but as `fn.call(window)`**

**The jsfiddle and code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jfp06nc9/7/

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    setTimeout(function() {
        "use strict";
        console.log(this); 
    }, 1000);
}());
```

**Since the function runs in strict mode, if it is run as a function, then `this` should be `undefined` but it is in fact `window`**

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, not in fiddles.

Comment: MDN [does explain this](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html#The_%27this%27_problem) in their documentation for `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Yes , it is true, windows has a lot of functions like alert, setTimeout, setInterval etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window that is why you are getting this as window object

Comment: Your question has, really, nothing to do with `setTimeout()`, but it has everything to do with how `this` works in Javascript.  It is different from other languages like Java, C++ and Python.   [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)  [explanation on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: why would he ask if he know that setTimeout() has nothing to do with `this` ...

Comment: @dsh isn't it true that I can implement a `setTimeout2` or `delayThis` that takes a function, and call it as a function, not as a method? (meaning that the behavior is up to the function, in this case, up to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` is part of the HTML spec (as opposed to ECMAScript), and it does indeed clarify that `window` should be used for `this`.

The [relevant part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) is as follows:

> 1. Let *method context proxy* be *method context* if that is a `WorkerGlobalScope` object, **or else the `WindowProxy` that corresponds to *method context***.

(emphasis mine)

along with:

> 4.2 Run the appropriate set of steps from the following list:
>
> If the first method argument is a Function
>
> Call the `Function`. Use the third and subsequent method arguments (if any) as the arguments for invoking the Function. **Use *method context proxy* as the `thisArg` for invoking the Function.**

(emphasis mine)