# Close submenu with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using `jQuery` to hide a sub-menu on `mouseleave`, everything works fine, but when I try to use `setTimeout` the function doesn't work.

This is my code without `setTimeout`

```
$( "li.menu-item" ).hover(function() {  // mouse enter
  $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).show(); // display child
}, function(){ // mouse leave
  $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).hide(); 
});
```

And with `setTimeout`:

```
$( "li.menu-item" ).hover(function() {  // mouse enter
  $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).show(); // display child
}, function(){ // mouse leave
  setTimeout(function () {
    $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).hide();
  }, 2000);            
});
```

The `setTimeout` function is working, if I insert an alert inside, the execution is with **2 seconds** delay.

Thank You.

Comment: This is because of `this`. Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Comment: Thak you for the resource and your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that `$(this)` will not read inside `setTimeout()`

```
$( "li.menu-item" ).hover(function() {  // mouse enter
  $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).show(); // display child
}, function(){ // mouse leave
  var ThisIt = $(this);    
  setTimeout(function () {
    ThisIt.find( ".sub-menu" ).hide();
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: @AritzMadariaga glad it helped .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Within setTimeout this has a different context, so you cannot target on "sub-menu". Keep a reference of this before setTimeout  and use that to reference "sub-menu" inside  setTimeout.