# Double the function in each request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timeout

In my nodejs app, i have a file with following contents:

**index.js** contents:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

function start(){
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        check();
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, 60000); // 1 minutes
}

function check(){
    // my custom codes....
    console.log('checked');
    start(); //return again to start
}

start();

http.listen(3008, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + 3008);
});
```

Up code most check every 60 seconds my `check` function.
this code is work, but there is a problem, when for example 5 users online in my app, i see in my console the `check` function after 60 seconds was repeated !

```
//First 60 seconds
checked

//Second 60 seconds
checked
checked

//third 60 seconds
checked
checked
checked
checked

// check function repated again in each 60 seconds !
```

i try test several way, but not work.

Comment: i use this file as an api for my site. this function check my users payment every 60 seconds, but the request was duble in next 60 sec.

Comment: In face, i need somthing to check a function in each 60 seconds

Comment: and i know, no body can help me to fix this solution.
Do you know what my superiority is over others?
With my own efforts, I can accurately, to the extent permitted, and pursue it.
I don't remember ever leaving any project unfinished.

And that's why I always have my customers. Something you can rarely see.
I will become stronger every day.

Comment: it's because your timer reference is not bound to the closure it is created in, when used in your setTimeout function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209784/variable-inside-settimeout-says-it-is-undefined-but-when-outside-it-is-defined

Comment: Thanks friend, i test this way and not work in my case. thanks

so, I never remember it being something and I couldn't make it. I would love to be something I can't make, but I'll do it anyway, and the standard of quality is my priority.

Anyway i will try to fix.

Comment: And one thing I forgot to say.
I have never worked for money, I have always worked out of curiosity. Maybe that's the key to my success over the rest. However, I know my income is higher than others. I'm never looking to be famous.
Read my words, it will help you along the way.Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setInterval(function, timeout);

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

function start(){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        check();
    }, 60000); // 1 minutes
}

function check(){
    // my custom codes....
    console.log('checked');
}

start();

http.listen(3008, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + 3008);
});
```

Comment: Thank, you will delete clearTimeout, and i know this code can't effect in this case,.

Comment: i always have 3 maps for my functions. so now I'm going to run the second map.  if not work, the third map should be work.

Comment: also, setInterval makes it worse.