# using setTimeout in each loop does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a huge galerie with about 400 pictures. I made a button so i can delete all pictures from the DOM and also from the server (by using an ajax request for each file).

I tried to use `setTimeout` inside my for each loop to give all items a background-color of red, just for testing. However nothing happens if i click my button!

```
    //run trough all pages
    pages.each
    (
        function()
        {
            var items = $(this).children("ul").children("li");

            //run through each item of the page
            items.each
            (
                function()
                {
                    setTimeout(function() { $(this).css("background-color","red"); }, 100);
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

If i run this code without setTimeout, then it works. I also tried other waiting times. No errors are thrown.

Comment: Note, when you run something in setTimeout, context changes and `this` will point to something else

Comment: Ahh i see... thanks.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
setTimeout(function(el) { el.css("background-color","red"); }, 100, $(this));
```