# Modify object property inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, properties, anonymous-function

I have the following code snippet:

```
if (this.y <= 0 || this.y >= screenHeight - this.h) {
    if (!this.verticalHit) {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
        this.verticalHit = true;
        setTimeout(function() {this.verticalHit = false;}, 500);
    }
}
```

This snippet is executed every frame and `verticalHit` is a property of the object where the code belongs to.

I want to modify `verticalHit`, as shown in the code above. However, it seems like `this` is overriden inside the anonymous function, and `verticalHit` is never going to be assigned `false`.

How could I solve this? Is there any way I could return from `setTimeout`?

Comment: Capture `this` in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arrow function or `.bind(this)` on the anonymous function. Currently, your `this` in the timeout is bound to the global object.

```
if (this.y <= 0 || this.y >= screenHeight - this.h) {
    if (!this.verticalHit) {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
        this.verticalHit = true;
        setTimeout(() => {this.verticalHit = false;}, 500);
    }
}
```

Here's another SO answer that addresses [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800171/5793033).