# JQuery get element in a setTimer function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event for click-and-hold on a dynamic element

```
    var timeoutId = 0;
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.createbtn', function(){
        timeoutId = setTimeout(showNewInfoCreateDlg, 1000);
    }).on('mouseup mouseleave', '.createbtn', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });
```

and the function is "showNewInfoCreateDlg"
I need to know what is the id of the element that was clicked-and-held

```
    function showNewInfoCreateDlg(){
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }
```

The function alerts "undefined"

Here is the jsfiddle for my problem:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9zrk1fb/2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly bind it to the function:

```
var timeoutId = 0;
$(document).on('mousedown', '.createbtn', function(){
    timeoutId = setTimeout(showNewInfoCreateDlg.bind(this), 1000);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', '.createbtn', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

To clarify: The `bind()` function will, well, bind the value of its first argument to the `this` variable inside `showNewInfoCreateDlg`. This is called explicit binding.