# Get "this" context in a JS "class" method function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a "class" in JS, a simplified structure of which is below:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/WpqYRP?editors=0010

```
function Alert() {
  this.message = "Test alert";
  this.document = $(document);

  this.document.on('click', function() {
     this.show();
  }.bind(this));

};

Alert.prototype.show = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.message);
  }, 50);
};

var alert = new Alert();
```

When you click on the `document` it should show you the `this.message` contents  in console. However, it is now shown as `undefined`. I believe the problem is that `this.messsage` can't get the original `this` context because it is wrapper in another function (`setTimeout` in my case). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Seriously, you have `bind` right there in your code already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me, you get your `this.message` by referencing `self`, which is the correct context you need.

```
function Alert() {  
  this.message = "Test alert";
  this.document = $(document);
  this.document.on('click', function() {
  this.show();
}.bind(this));
};
Alert.prototype.show = function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(self.message);
  }, 50);
};
var alert = new Alert();
```

Comment: Thanks! Both methods worked fine, just found this one a little simplier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions which will preserve your **this** context.

```
function Alert() {
  this.message = "Test alert";
  this.document = $(document);

  this.document.on('click', () => {
     this.show();
  });

};

Alert.prototype.show = function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.message);
  }, 50);
};

var alert = new Alert();
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arrow_functions.