# How can I prevent onscroll function to trigger during resize?

Tags: javascript, events, operator-precedence, onscroll, onresize

I have two event handlers defined:

`window.onresize = repositionElements;`

`scrollElement.onscroll = handleScrollBusiness;`

Now, when I resize the window, I do *not* want my onscroll event to fire (which it ususally does during resizing). So I thought I temporarily set some `isResizing` variable to `true` and only set it back to `false` after a timeout. In the onscroll function I would then first of all check, if `isResizing` is false and only then proceed.

However, now during testing this, I realized that when I start to resize the window, it both fires a scroll and resize event, but it fires the `onscroll` event *first*, so my `onresize` has no chance to disable the scroll function, since it only gets fired after the scroll function has started to execute.

Is there any way around this? Can I globally change the order of these two events? If not, what other way would there to disable the onscroll event immediately once I start resizing?

I am looking for an answer in vanilla JavaScript. Also I am new to this, so if I have some logical flaws in my way to approach this, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't posted an example code of your problem, I'm not sure if what I'm about to write helps you or not.

---

You could try to defer the execution of `onscroll` handler by wrapping it's code inside a zero-length timeout, which effectively moves the execution of that piece of code to the end of current execution stack.

Here's an example:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // your code here...
    }, 0);
}

window.onresize = function () {
    // your code here...
    // should be executed before onscroll handler
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. If others are in the same situation: It *did* cause my function not to work properly anymore, since I was passing a `this` which was overwritten by the setTimeout, but another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback) helped me, I just needed to save my `this` into another variable before calling `setTimeout` and then use that variable within the function and so it worked again. Thanks again, mdziekon!

Comment: You could also use arrow functions to preserve ``this`` value.

Comment: As a newbie I have no idea what arrow function are, but I will make sure to read up about them. :)

Comment: One of the reasons they were introduced in ES2015 was to remove the need to preserve ``this`` value. You can read more about them at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RxJs Observable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCqaPsm8_VAhVBqo8KHdZpBcgQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FReactive-Extensions%2FRxJS&usg=AFQjCNHrMHDtQDbLhov4sutULxApsgoF-g) for this:

```
var resizeOb$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize');
var scrolOb$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
              .takeUntil(resizeOb$);
scrolOb$.subscribe(function(event){

     /* handle scroll event here */
});
resizeOb$.subscribe(function(event){

     /* handle resize event here */
});
```

This will efficiently handle the situation for you.

Comment: OP has asked for "vanilla JS" solution. This requires an additional library.

Comment: But, still this could be efficient solution for others to follow.