# When writing a debounce, what is the point of fn.apply(context, args)?

Tags: javascript

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timer = null;
  // this1
  return function() {
    let context = this, args = arguments;
    // context = this2
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      // this3
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  }
}

var debouncedFn = debounce(function() {
  console.log('hi');
}, 50);

debouncedFn();
```

Are `this1`, `this2`, and `this3` not the same? What is the intention of `fn.apply()`? Why do we choose to `fn.apply(this2)` and not just `fn()` or `fn.apply(this1)` or `fn.apply(this3)` in this case?

Comment: Each function has its own context, when you use `fn.apply(context, args)` you are overriding the function's context with your own. This'd let you access variables on `this` that otherwise would not be accessible from the target function

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use an arrow function which binds `this` lexically to that of the surrounding anonymous function and write `timer = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, arguments), delay);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To preserve the context (the value of this) of the debounced function.
2. To handle unknown number of arguments.

**1.**

The function may get attached to an object, so when calling the function the context should be that object. The function that get attached to such object is not `fn`, it's the anonymous function returned by `debounce`. So when calling `fn` we have to call it with the same context as that anonymous function using either `call` or `apply`.

**2.**

The function that actually get called is the anonymous function, that will then call `fn` after some time. Since we don't know how many arguments does `fn` have, we just call it with all the arguments that the anonymous function get called with using the `arguments` object and `aplly` (`call` won't be used here as it takes separate argument not grouped-in-array-like arguments).

**The thisN question:**

No, they're not the same.

`this1` is going to be `window` as `debounce` is not attached to any object.

`this2` could be `window` or could be anything else depending on how you call `debounce`:

```
var f = debounde(someFn, 100);   // this2 is window
var obj = {};
obj.f = debounce(someFn, 100);   // this2 is obj
```

`this3` is also `window`, due to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback).

Answer (score 3):

Let`s add some names to functions

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timer = null;
  return function functionX() {
    let context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function functionY() {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  }
}

var debouncedFn = debounce(function functionZ() {
  console.log('hi');
}, 50);

debouncedFn();
```

**Why `.apply()`?:** Here `debouncedFn` holds the reference of `functionX`, that means if you execute `debouncedFn`, `functionX` will be executed. Now when you pass `n` number of parameters to `debouncedFn`, those can be retrieved in `functionX` via a reserved keyword `arguments`. Ultimately, you want your arguments to be supplied to `fn`, so for passing those arguments to `fn` we have to use `apply()`. For more info, please follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

**`this1, this2, this3:`** `debounce` is always executed globally, that is why it's context is `window`, `functionX()` can be attached to an `object`, that is why context of `functionX()` will be object in which you are putting `debouncedFn()` and context of `setTimeout` is again `window` because of global execution. See following example for better understanding of context.

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timer = null;
  console.log('this1', this.name);
  return function() {
    let context = this,
      args = arguments;
    console.log('this2', this.name);
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       console.log('this3', this.name);
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  }
}


var person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  getName: debounce(function() {
    console.log('hi');
  }, 50)
}

person.getName();
person.getName();
```

Comment: Very well described