# Passing variable to function within class method

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have a class I am attempting to write that looks like the below.

When I run the class, I get an error:

`Audio.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: bufferLength is not defined`

I believe this is because `bufferLength` is not available in the `drawCanvas` function.

I have tried adding the `this` keyword, however this did not work.

How can I make these variables available to functions within a method of this class?

```
export const LINE_COLORS = ['rgba(255, 23, 204, 0.5)', 'rgba(130, 23, 255, 0.5)'];

// The dimensions of the current viewport
// - Used to set canvas width & height
export const PAGE_DIMENSIONS = {
  width: window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight,
};

class AudioEngine {
  constructor(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.audio = new Audio();
    this.ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    this.analyser = this.ctx.createAnalyser();
    this.source = this.ctx.createMediaElementSource(this.audio);
    this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    this.bufferLength = this.analyser.frequencyBinCount;

    this.canvas = document.getElementById(params.waveform);

    this.onInit();
  }

  onInit() {
    this.ConfigAudio();
    this.DrawAudioWave();
  }

  ConfigAudio = () => {
    this.audio.src = this.params.stream;
    this.audio.controls = false;
    this.audio.autoplay = false;
    this.audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    this.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.6;
    this.source.connect(this.ctx.destination);
    this.source.connect(this.analyser);
    this.analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.dataArray);

    document.body.appendChild(this.audio);
  };

  DrawAudioWave = () => {
    // Bind to the context
    const canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    function drawCanvas() {
      // We always start the drawing function by clearing the canvas. Otherwise
      // we will be drawing over the previous frames, which gets messy real quick
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, PAGE_DIMENSIONS.width, PAGE_DIMENSIONS.height);
      requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
      const sliceWidth = (PAGE_DIMENSIONS.width * 1.0) / bufferLength;
      // Create a new bounding rectangle to act as our backdrop, and set the
      // fill color to black.
      canvasCtx.fillStyle = '#000';
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, PAGE_DIMENSIONS.width, PAGE_DIMENSIONS.height);

      // Loop over our line colors. This allows us to draw two lines with
      // different colors.
      LINE_COLORS.forEach((color, index) => {
        let x = 0;
        // Some basic line width/color config
        canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        canvasCtx.strokeStyle = color;

        // Start drawing the path
        canvasCtx.beginPath();
        for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
          // We offset using the loops index (stops both colored lines
          // from overlapping one another)
          const v = dataArray[i] / 120 + index / 20;
          // Set the Y point to be half of the screen size (the middle)
          const y = (v * PAGE_DIMENSIONS.height) / 2;

          if (i === 0) {
            canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
          } else {
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
          }

          x += sliceWidth;
        }
        canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
        canvasCtx.stroke();
      });
    }
    drawCanvas();
  };

  audioToggle = () => (this.audio.paused ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause());
}

export default AudioEngine;
```

Comment: Something else I noticed with your code. You are calling `requestAnimationFrame` before the main body of your function, which means you can have race conditions. You should move the request to after your function's body executes, or look into clearing/cancelling previous requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requestAnimationFrame will call drawCanvas with the global context bound, so `this.bufferLength` will not be defined. Easiest solution is to take advantage of [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), which arrow functions make easy.

If you look at how you're defining your class's methods, they're using arrow functions. This is precisely to avoid the issue with rebinding `this` that you're currently having. You should read up on [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and scoping in JavaScript to better understand why your code isn't working as you'd expect.

Couple solutions, both require `drawCanvas -> this.drawCanvas`:

(A) Bind the context of drawCanvas before passing it to requestAnimationFrame:

`requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas.bind(this))`

Or (B) take advantange of lexical scoping:

`requestAnimationFrame(() => drawCanvas())`

"Lexical" scope is scope derived from the "text", i.e. where your arrow function is defined relative to other scopes. Non-lexical scoping uses the caller function to determine bound context.

You can also change the `drawCanvas` function itself to be bound to the appropriate scope using `.bind` or changing it to an arrow function.

**Further Reading**:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)
- [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback) (replace `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame` in their examples)