# TypeScript bind context

Tags: typescript, bind, private

I have a class containing function `private receiveCheck` and `protected dispatch`. I also want to call the private function in a callback, which I tried to bind to `this`.

```
protected dispatch(ajaxParams: JQuery.AjaxSettings<any>): void {
    ajaxParams.success = ((a: any, b: any) => {
        console.log(this)
        this.receiveCheck(0)
    }).bind(this)

    $.ajax(ajaxParams);
}
```

Unfortunately when the anonymous function is executed, it throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.receiveCheck is not a function

EDIT: The log in the output is the Window object. Removing the `bind` call does not solve this problem.

Comment: If available, try using `private static receiveCheck `

Comment: Receive check needs to access the object's properties, so using `static` is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you run the `dispatch` method? Use arrow method to avoid loosing this

```
    public dispatch = (): void =>  {
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: It is run from the subclass via `super.dispatch(..)`. (`this.dispatch` did not work) Changing the function to arrow method generates compile time error: `Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.`

Comment: Let's go deeper :) How do run this subclass method? It is callback?

Comment: Yes. It is called in a function, which is invoked via `setTimeout`.

Comment: Ok, so change the subclass method to arrow.

Comment: That did the trick. :-) Could you please provide an explanation in your answer?

Comment: Sure :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130411/11610862 - when you call the method via `setTimeout` it loses `this` context, but not `super`, so the problem only appears in the `dispatch` method. You can look at typescript output code, to understand how `super` works.

Answer (score 0):

You use an arraow function, so the this context is binded to the upper function anyway. You could simply remove the bind

```
class Example {
  public do() {
    console.log('doPublic');
    const fn = () => {
      this.doProtected();
    };
    fn();
  }

  protected doProtected() {
    console.log('doProtected');
  }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log('start');
e.do();
```

https://codepen.io/ste-xx/pen/qzaeRx?editors=1111

Comment: The same error is still present even without the `bind` call.