# function call within setTimeout not executing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am executing the function `delayFilter()` on keyup of an input box. I want to delay 1 second after the user stops typing and run the function `filterProducts()`. However, when executing `filterProducts()` inside of the setTimeout I get the console error "this.filterProducts is not a function". This function gets called fine when outside of the setTimeout. Why is this error being thrown?

```
  delayFilter() {
    let timeout = null;
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      this.filterProducts();
    }, 1000);
  }

  filterProducts() {
    //do stuff
  }
```

Comment: This is a context issue. Not an issue with setTimeout.

Comment: Using `clearTimeout` directly after overwriting your refernce to the timeout (`timeout = null`) isn't going to have the desired effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because these,  this inside the callback, does not refer to the object outside.

Try this:

```
delayFilter() {
    let timeout = null;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    let self = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      self.filterProducts();
    }, 1000);
  }

  filterProducts() {
    //do stuff
  }
```

You can also try the arrow function. The reason can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

```
delayFilter() {
    let timeout = null;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.filterProducts();
    }, 1000);
  }

  filterProducts() {
    //do stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the scope of the function in the `setTimeout` callback. the easiest way is to use arrow functions, if your platform supports it.

```
timeout = setTimeout(() => this.filterProducts(), 1000);
```

you can also save the scope in a variable.

```
var self = this;
timeout = setTimeout(funciton() { self.filterProducts() }, 1000);
```

Alternatively you can manually bind it. This is useful if you want to pass the function around.

```
timeout = setTimeout(function() {...}.bind(this), 1000);
```