# Code inside arrow function of setInterval not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I did see multiple questions related to mine but I couldn't find a proper answer.
This is my code but the function inside setInterval is not working.
makeAPICall() is not called and the log also didn't execute. Any answer is appreciated.

P.s. I am a newbie so please ignore any mistakes

Code

```
fetchData() {
        reactotron.log('called!!');
        if (this.props.isConnected) {
            clearInterval(bgTimer);
            bgTimer = setInterval(() => {
                reactotron.log('inside setTimer callback');
                this.makeAPICall();
            }, 20000);
        }
    }
```

bgTimer is declared above class definition

```
let bgTimer;

class MyScreen extends Component {
```

Comment: There's no `=>` function in the code you posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the function inside setInterval is not working*"? Is it called or not? Does it result in an error? Does it execute successfully but produce the wrong result?

Comment: Define "not working." There's so little context here it'd be difficult to provide any meaningful help.

Comment: With that said, *most likely* the problem is that you aren't using an arrow function but you should. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) and [Pass correct “this” context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130241)

Comment: because it will be executed in 20 seconds?

Comment: Please log and see what this.props.isConnected have. Probably its failing on this condition and never goes to run the timer