# setInterval can't find function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement an autosave feature, where every 10 minutes it calls the save function. However if I use `setInterval()` it throws an error, stating `this.createMapXML is not a function`. But if I call the save function manually (e.g. by pressing a button) it works.

The code:

```
startautoSave(){setInterval(this.uploadToDataBase, 600000)};

uploadToDataBase(){
    this.toUploadMap.xml = this.createMapXML();
.
.
.
}
createMapXML(): string {. . .}
```

Comment: `setInterval(this.uploadToDataBase, 600000)` -> `setInterval(() => this.uploadToDataBase(), 600000)`

Comment: Also relevant: [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130241)