# Javascript "this" variable switching from specific object to DOMWindow

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a problem with Javascript forcing the [object DOMWindow] into an function I have in an object's prototype. The full error I get is below:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'positionconvert'`

Basically what I'm doing is inside the object prototype under certain conditions I'm creating a `var interval` that counts off with `window.setInterval()`:

`var interval = window.setInterval(this.alertanimate, 500);`

the `alertanimate` function is inside the same prototype, and uses the `this` variable in this line:

`this.positionconvert(this.alerticon, -69, 55);`

(positionconvert is yet another function, and alerticon is an object). The problem is when I get `window.setInterval` involved js starts assuming `this` is the DOM and not the object prototype, like I intended, presenting the above error. When I hard-code this to work with a specific object it works, but somewhere in this variable-passing the `this` variable loses its connection to the object. I hope this all makes sense? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout and "this" in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `this.alertanimate` to `setIntervall` loses the connection to the main object. What `this` refers to in a function is entirely defined by **how** the function is called.
If you pass a function to `setTimeout` then `this` will refer to `window`.

You can do:

```
var self = this;

window.setInterval(function() {
    self.alertanimate();
}, 500);
```

In newer browsers, you can also use [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (see docs for an alternative implementation):

```
window.setInterval(this.alertanimate.bind(this), 500);
```

Comment: Oh my god that did it. I had tried the `var me = this;` trick and passing `me` into `alertanimate(me);` like that, but you have it right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to JavaScript.  The `this` is re-bound every time you introduce a function scope.

```
    var outer = function() {
      var that = this;
      // that and this refer to the same object: outer
      var inner = function() {
        // now that refers to outer and this refers to inner
        ...
      }
      // that and this again refer to the same object: outer
      ...
    }
```

You didn't post your full code, but I suspect one of your inner `this`'s doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: Ahh that's a good illustration. Yeah I didn't think my full code was necessary to communicate the problem, but this is a good way of explaining it. Thanks.