# How to chain async methods in javascript ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, chaining

I want to chain methods from a class.  I have o problems with synchronous methods, but I don't know how to do it with asynchronous methods.

For example, this class:

```
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.val = 0
  }

  async () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.val += 1
      return this
    }, 5000)
  }

  sync () {
    this.val += 1
    return this
  }

  check () {
    console.log('checker', this.val)
    return this
  }

}
```

This works:

```
new Example().sync().check()
> 1
```

But this doesn't work:

```
new Example().async().check()
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined
```

P.S. I want chaining, not Hell Callbacks.

Comment: First of all, `async` is not ES6 but a proposal for ES7.

Comment: You should be using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not attempting to shift `this` references around. You'll not have that syntax still (until async/await arrive in ES7) but at least you can avoid callback hell

Comment: As an aside, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591343/2039244) for a little info about the execution context of a function given to `setTimeout` and why doing `return this` doesn't work like you want it to.

Comment: You'd need to keep track internally whether the async method is done or not and have `check` monitor that. Btw, this has nothing to do with ES6 or classes (except promises are ES6, but they existed before that as well).

Comment: If you want to chain async operations (like jQuery does with animations), then you can build a queue (or use promises) where each method can be stored until the previous async operation completes and can trigger the next operation and each async method and sync method that you want to work with this will have to notify the queue when they are done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that you want to call `check()` after the timeout has expired. The problem is that forks off, and you can't immediately have something available to return.

You could pass in `check()` as a callback:

```js
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.val = 0
  }

  async (callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.val += 1
      callback()
    }, 5000)
  }

  sync () {
    this.val += 1
    return this
  }

  check () {
    console.log('checker', this.val)
    return this
  }

}

// execution
var ex = new Example();
ex.async(ex.check)
```

... or a promise

```js
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.val = 0
  }

  async (callback) {
    var deferred = Q.defer()
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.val += 1
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 5000)
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  sync () {
    this.val += 1
    return this
  }

  check () {
    console.log('checker', this.val)
    return this
  }

}

// execution
var ex = new Example()
ex.async().then(() => ex.check())
```

... Or you could use ES6 generators

Comment: `check()` is not a method call here. You should resolve with  `this` and do `ex => ex.check()`

Comment: Thanks you, i was looking for a way to chain asynchronous functions like that :
new Example().async().sync().async().sunc() and so on ..
But the only solutions are callbacks ( break the chain because next method is called in an anonymous functions ) and promises that breaks also the chain ( because next methods are also called inside an anonymous functions )..
So to "chain" asynchronous functions THE solution would be to queue methods ?

Comment: @rdbmax: the problem is that you cannot have really synchronous functions in a chain that involves asynchrony. You either can call synchronous methods from callbacks that are explicitly attached to the asynchronous actions, or you make all your methods asynchronous and put the (synchronous) actions on some queue managed in the instance state.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the ES6 generator example. :-(

Comment: Sorry dashmug. I basically put that as a personal challenge to learn it, then got too busy. I'll remove the "example coming" bit.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is `new Example().async().check()` to work, all you need to do is `return this` after you call setTimeout. Ex:

```
async () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.val += 1
  }, 5000)
  return this
}
```

The `return this` inside the timeout isn't necessary, since it'll be executing on its own. It's basically running stand alone at that point.

Really, if you want this whole thing to be running async completely, and you're able to control flow of when certain things occur, you need to be using promises to make that happen.

Comment: That doesn't do the expected thing, though.

Comment: What is 'the expected thing'? I feel like this question should probably be on the code review site more than SO.

Comment: I assumed they wanted `sync` to be called once the 5000ms timeout was resolved.

Comment: I expect he wants to run `check()` after the timeout has expired.

Comment: I don't see that basis in the question, Bergi.. That's why promises wasn't originally part of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I need to run check() after the timeout has expired.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `async` functions and methods, you are using promises (I suppose you know them, if not please learn about them before reading on).

You should not use `setTimeout` inside of an asynchronous function if you consider waiting for it. Instead, create a promise for the timeout, preferably using a helper function like this:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    });
}
```

Now you can write your method like you'd really want to:

```
class Example {
  …
  async async () {
    await timeout(5000);
    this.val += 1;
    return this;
  }
  …
}
```

Of course, as an `async` function it does not return the instance itself, but a promise for it. If you are going to chain, you will have to call it inside of another asynchronous function where you can `await` that promise:

```
(async function() {
    (await (new Example().async())).check();
}());
```

Comment: Oops, I assumed the OP was talking about [`async` methods](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait) and used `async` as the keyword, not for a method name. I see now it's not what he meant, but I still think the answer is useful so I won't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for will be solved most elegantly by [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You'll need to likely install a polyfill, like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

I would change your async method to:

```
async() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.val += 1;
            resolve(this);
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

And your calling code to:

```
new Example().async().then((instance)=>instance.check());
```

Unfortunately, until ES7 async functions are nailed down, there won't be an elegant way to do this without some form of callback.

Comment: ES6 includes Promises. No polyfill needed.

Comment: Well, it does... But unless you're in a perfect world or on the server, we're going to need to wait for IE11 to go the way of the dodo... It's just easier to include a polyfill for web work.

Comment: Well, the question does have the node tag. Writing ES6 for browsers seems a bit premature, though I suppose if you don't care about any backwards compatibility, it would mostly work...

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that node tag. Makes much more sense.