# Why is 'this' undefined inside class method when using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, this, q

I have a javascript class, and each method returns a `Q` promise. I want to know why `this` is undefined in `method2` and `method3`. Is there a more correct way to write this code?

```
function MyClass(opts){
  this.options = opts;

  return this.method1()
    .then(this.method2)
    .then(this.method3);
}

MyClass.prototype.method1 = function(){
  // ...q stuff...

  console.log(this.options); // logs "opts" object

  return deferred.promise;
};

MyClass.prototype.method2 = function(method1resolve){
  // ...q stuff...

  console.log(this); // logs undefined

  return deferred.promise;
};

MyClass.prototype.method3 = function(method2resolve){
  // ...q stuff...

  console.log(this); // logs undefined

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

I can fix this by using `bind`:

```
function MyClass(opts){
  this.options = opts;

  return this.method1()
    .then(this.method2.bind(this))
    .then(this.method3.bind(this));
}
```

But not entirely sure why `bind` is necessary; is `.then()` killing `this` off?

Comment: When you use bind() it creates another function with exactly the scope you will pass by params. Although It answers just your last question, take a look at the Mozila's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: In 8 words, explain how the heck is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises) a duplicate of [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript)?

I just had this exact same question come up, which would _not_ have been answered by [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript). I know [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript) already, but I'm coming to terms with promises, ES6 Classes, and `this`.

Comment: @Paulpro not so sure this should be marked as a duplicate of the [`setTimeout` issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript); as the problem arises in two completely different ways. People looking to resolve their `this` scoping issues in the context of promises are immediately being pointed to a more indirect question, where the accepted answer uses anti-patterns from 2009. `2 + 2 = 4` !== `((8+2)*6)/15 = 4`

Comment: IMO definitely shouldn't be marked as a duplicate especially to a question about timeouts. This question specifically about Promises and the answers are a god send. Thank you.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

`this` is always the object the method is called on. However, when passing the method to `then()`, you are not calling it! The method will be stored somewhere and called from there later. If you want to preserve `this`, you will have to do it like this:

```
.then(() => this.method2())
```

or if you have to do it the pre-ES6 way, you need to preserve `this` before:

```
var that = this;
// ...
.then(function() { that.method2() })
```

Comment: great answer - or pre-ES6 ".then(this.method2.bind(this))"

Comment: I used `.then(data => this.method(data))`

Comment: FAR FAR easyer way:
.then(( foo = this) => {...
//then use foo instead of this    [also translates to the pre-es6 version]

Just make sure it's not overwridden!

Comment: underrated explanation, struggled with this quite a bit when setting up promises, now fixex. thanks

Answer (score 25):

Promise handlers are called in the context of the global object (`window`) by default. When in strict mode (`use strict;`), the context is `undefined`. This is what's happening to `method2` and `method3`.

```
;(function(){
  'use strict'
  Promise.resolve('foo').then(function(){console.log(this)}); // undefined
}());

;(function(){
  Promise.resolve('foo').then(function(){console.log(this)}); // window
}());
```

For `method1`, you're calling `method1` as `this.method1()`. This way of calling it calls it in the context of the `this` object which is your instance. That's why the context inside `method1` is the instance.

Comment: Now **this** is an answer **that** helped me to understand **it**.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you're passing it a function reference with no context reference. The `this` context is determined in a few ways:

1. Implicitly. Calling a global function or a function without a binding assumes a global context.*
2. By direct reference. If you call `myObj.f()` then `myObj` is going to be the `this` context.**
3. Manual binding. This is your class of functions such as `.bind` and `.apply`. These you explicitly state what the `this` context is. These always take precedence over the previous two.

In your example, you're passing a function reference, so at it's invocation it's implied to be a global function or one without context. Using `.bind` resolves this by creating a new function where `this` is explicitly set.

*This is only true in non-strict mode. In strict mode, `this` is set to `undefined`.

**Assuming the function you're using hasn't been manually bound.

Answer (score 1):

One way functions get their context (`this`) is from the object on which they are invoked (which is why `method1` has the right context - it's invoked on `this`). You are passing a reference to the function itself to `then`. You can imagine that the implementation of `then` looks something like this:

```
function then( callback ) {

  // assume 'value' is the recently-fulfilled promise value
  callback(value);
}
```

In that example `callback` is a reference to your function. It doesn't have any context. As you've already noted you can get around that by binding the function to a context before you pass it to then.