# 'this' is undefined inside function(). angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I am using a [uikit confirmation modal](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal) in my app. My problem is, when I am going to click the `<button>` for confirmation. the `this` inside function is `undefined`. here's my code...

```
declare var UIkit:any;

deleteData(dataArr): void {

    UIkit.modal.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?', function() {
      console.log(dataArr);
      console.log(this);
      //use service here...
      UIkit.modal.alert('Confirmed!');  
    });
}
```

Inside that function I wish to use service for http request but I am having a problem on the `this`. I am using Angular 2.x.

Comment: `() => {` ... ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout and "this" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript) | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an arrow function...

```
declare var UIkit:any;

deleteData(dataArr): void {

  UIkit.modal.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?', () => {

    console.log(this);
    // [...]
  });
}
```

Check out [MDN: Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for details on the matter.

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so `this` has
>   its original meaning from the enclosing context.

Comment: wow. that was pretty easy. i thought im going to use bind. anyway thank you. it worked now

Comment: What if you have a common function like a string filter on one of many arrays, with the same global input var? I've got 5 lists I can add/remove things from. When removing, I want to use array.filter(my_class_filter_func()). But the call to my_class_filter_func() gives "this" is null or undefined. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

'this' is not passed to your function scope, try

```
declare var UIkit:any;

deleteData(dataArr): void {
var that = this;
UIkit.modal.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?', function(){
  console.log(dataArr);
  console.log(that);
  //use service here...
  UIkit.modal.alert('Confirmed!');  
});
}
```

Comment: thanks. this worked to. but im going to use the () => { I think this is the standards for ecma scripts.