# How can I access an Angular class variable without using `this`?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any way to use access the variable `MyVariable` from the `StartPage` class without using `this.`? The reason I am asking is that I need to reference this in a function, and `this` does not work there. I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703979/this-is-undefined-inside-function-angular-2) that I could use `=> {...` but that won't always work for me. How can I do this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.page.scss'],
})
export class StartPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  MyVariable = "Value";

  ngOnInit() {
   console.log(MyVariable); 
   //anyway to use MyVariable without `this.` prefix?
  }

}
```

Comment: Does `bind(this)` work for you?

Comment: Have you tried passing it into `ngOnInit`?

Comment: `The reason I am asking is that I need to reference this in a function` <= Could you share that code? Chances are you are just not binding `this` or you could be using a lambda but you were not aware how to.

Comment: Consider using `this`. Your team mates and future self will thank you. If you had trouble with a specific arrow function, please post the code for it and we can help. There should not be a case where an arrow function "doesn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I need to reference this in a function, and this does not work`

I think this is because you tried to access from a callback function (subscription, setTimeout or similar) and this is not defined in the context. For having access to this as a reference of StartPage class, you must bind the reference to this to the function, for example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.page.scss'],
})
export class StartPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  MyVariable = "Value";

  ngOnInit() {
     this.myFunction().bind(this);
  }

  myFunction(){
     // ...
     this.MyVariable = someValue
     // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems like that would work. But is there any other way to do this? Could I do something like `StartPage.MyVariable` ?

Comment: @nachshonf That syntax is how you access static variables. If you want to access an instance variable, you have to refer to an actual instance.

Comment: @nachshonf `StartPage.MyVariable` would be something like a constant value, instead of a instance of the object itself. I can't tell if it could be done as far I know