# Calling method from promise

Tags: javascript, this, chaining

Hello I have object which contains few methods. In one of them I am using promise to execute another one and I am using `.then` to retrieve some data from it.

Within `.then` my `this` keyword is changed and I can not figure out how to call again another method from this point.

So the method I'm writing about is:

```
    convertToUSD: function(selectedCurrency,priceField) {
        var priceField = priceField;
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;

        console.log('selectedCurrency in service: '+selectedCurrency);
        console.log('priceField in service: '+priceField);

        var currentCurrency = this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);
        currentCurrency.then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('to USD: '+response.toUSD);
            if(response.toUSD !== undefined){
                var userPriceInUSD = priceField*response.toUSD;
                console.log(userPriceInUSD);
                this.addTax(userPriceInUSD);
            };
        });

    },
```

inside `if()` statement I'm doing a simple calculation and then I want to pass the result to `addTax()` method (in the very same object) but `this` keyword doesn't work as expected in this case, so how can I start another method at this point? And less important question - is this what I'm doing named chaining?

Comment: solution 1 - use an arrow function `.then((response) => {` - solution two, save a reference to this, say in `var _this = this;` outside that .then function, and use _this inside it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises

Comment: knew there was a dupe :p

Comment: Sorry for duplicate I was looking for answer but couldn't find good keywords. Now I know how to accomplish that. Last question - is it chaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the context of this in that, then use this new variable **that** to do operations

```
convertToUSD: function(selectedCurrency,priceField) {
        var priceField = priceField;
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;

        console.log('selectedCurrency in service: '+selectedCurrency);
        console.log('priceField in service: '+priceField);
        var that = this; // this stores the context of this in that
        var currentCurrency = this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);
        currentCurrency.then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('to USD: '+response.toUSD);
            if(response.toUSD !== undefined){
                var userPriceInUSD = priceField*response.toUSD;
                console.log(userPriceInUSD);
                that.addTax(userPriceInUSD);
            };
        });

    },
```