# How to to push fetched data from backend service into a declared property within a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm setting up a Angular Service to retrieve dummy data from an API and push the 3 first elements to a TypeScript Class property, but I'm getting this error: 
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Making use of `fetch` method and a `for` loop, I'm trying to push the 3 first returned objects to a declared, empty property within the class, however, I get an error when trying to push the data. I'm not able to see the cause of the problem.

```
export class DishService {

  group = [];

  constructor() {     
  }

  fetchIt() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(json){
      for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
        console.log(json[i])
        this.group.push(json[i])
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: in the second `then` block, try changing `function(json){` to `(json) => {`, if that fixes it I'll write up an answer.

Comment: How and when are you calling `fetchIt` method?

Comment: @pizzaisdavid, That worked like a charm, I investigated and found out that fat arrows does not have a context and that's why using it, the "this" takes the context of the class... Thanks for the hint buddy.

Comment: @veben , I'm injecting this "super noob tiny" service into another component, and I'm calling it within it's `ngOnInit()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that "this" is undefined, that is because "this" refers to the object which contains the method being invoked, in your case - "then", and not the DishService class.

You can use arrow function as suggested here:
[Why is 'this' undefined inside class method when using promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises)