# Can't access this.setState inside 2nd API call in nested calls (AWS Amplify Storage API) (React Native)

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, this, setstate, aws-amplify

- The first call (Storage.list('s3 bucket path')) returns a list of keys.
- For each key, I make a second call (Storage.get('key')) that returns a url
- Inside the first AND second API call I console.log and get the correct data I need for each.
- this.setState works perfectly inside the first API call, but it doesn't inside the second one.

My code is:

```
    state = { keyItems: [], urlItems: [] }

    componentDidMount() {
        Storage.list('')
          .then(keyItems => {
            console.log("keyItems: ", keyItems)
            this.setState({ keyItems: keyItems })

            /*for each photo key in the folder..*/
            keyItems.forEach(function(keyItem) {
              /*get the URL*/
              Storage.get(keyItem.key)
                .then(urlItem => {
                  console.log("urlItem: ", urlItem)
                  /*add URL item to state*/
                  /*ANY CALL TO this.setState HERE DOESN'T WORK, i've tried 
                  even simple tests*/
                  this.setState(prevState => ({ urlItems:[...prevState.urlItems, { key: keyItem.key, source: urlItem } ]}))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log("error fetching photo URL", err)
                })
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("error fetching photos keys", err)
          })
      }
```

Console: 
[image: Console]

- I've tried making the calls from arrow functions outside the componentDidMount but still can't access the this.setState

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is getting lost inside the `.then`

You could try this

1. Set `this` to a variable
2. Use that variable instead of `this`

Here it in code

```
componentDidMount () {
  const that = this;

  // now call setState like this
  that.setState(...)

}
```

You can read more about it at the link below, but I’ve put the general gist of it here.

> `this` is always the object the method is called on. However, when
>   passing the method to `then()`, you are not calling it! The method
>   will be stored somewhere and called from there later.

[Why is 'this' undefined inside class method when using promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises)