# Call Method of class after Promise is fullfilled

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a simple class

```
class A{
  constructor(){
   this.loadComponents().then(function(values) {callbackOnLoad();});
  }

  callbackOnLoad(){
  //do some things
  }

  loadComponents(){
    ...
    return Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8]);
  }
}
```

I am unable to call callbackOnLoad after all promises are fulfilled. I know that "this" depends on the caller and so I understand why callbackOnLoad does not work. How can I solve this problem? How do I have to structure/design my code?

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do it would be calling then & catch immediately after `Promise.all`.

```
class A{
  constructor() {
    this.loadComponents();
  }

  callbackOnLoad = () => {
    //do some things
  }

  loadComponents = () => {
    return Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8]).then((values) => {
      this.callbackOnLoad();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between my and your code? Is it just the long arrow function? Whould this also work:   constructor(){
   this.loadComponents().then((values) =>{callbackOnLoad();});
  }