# JS class - 'this' is undefined in promise

Tags: javascript, class, fetch, es6-promise

There is a Class and inside if this class I'm trying to fill up an array winch was defined in 'constructor'.

```
 class ClassA {

   constructor(){
      ...
      this.place = [];
   }

   fillUp() {
      fetch(path)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(result) {

         this.place.push({"result":result})
        })
    }
 }
inst = new ClassA();   
inst.fillUp();
```

As a result i got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'place' of undefined.
Where could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 'this' undefined inside class method when using promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises)

Comment: Because you are inside a promise thenable, "this" now points to the thenable. You will need to do something like const self = this; as the first line in your fillUp function. Then instead of writing this.place.push, you would write self.place.push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in javascript is weird. Depending on how the code/function is called on the object, it may return values you did not expect. If you are using modern javascript, you should use short arrow notation. This will preserve what `this` is binded to. Otherwise, you will have to add `.bind(this)` to the function where you are referencing `this`:

```
fetch(path)
    .then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((result)=>{
        this.place.push({"result":result})
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your issue by using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in the callback attempting to `push` into the array. The problem with using a typical function expression is that it creates its own binding to the `this` keyword. Arrow functions on the other hand:

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the `this`
>   from its enclosing scope.

Therefore, you if you use an arrow function in the callback, the function will take `this` from it's enclosing scope (i.e.: the `ClassA` object).

Here's a demo of how it might work:

```js
const mockFetch = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Fetching data..please wait..')
  setTimeout(() => resolve({
    json: () => '{ data: \'Some response data\'}'
  }), 1500)
});


class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    this.place = [];
  }

  fillUp() {
    mockFetch.then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(result => {
      this.place.push({
        "result": result
      });
      console.log(this.place);
    })
  }
}

inst = new ClassA();
inst.fillUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function.

```
 class ClassA {

   constructor(){
      ...
      this.place = [];
   }

   fillUp = () => {
      fetch(path)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(result) {

         this.place.push({"result":result})
        })
    }
 }
inst = new ClassA();   
inst.fillUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

The promise handlers are different functions with different `this` values.

To make the `this` equal inside, you can use arrow functions, which inherit `this` from where they've been defined:

```js
class ClassA {

   constructor(){
      ...
      this.place = [];
   }

   fillUp() {
      fetch(path)
        .then(response =>  response.json())
        .then(result => {
          this.place.push({"result":result})
        })
      }
    }
inst = new ClassA();   
inst.fillUp();
```

Or, `.bind()` the functions:

```js
class ClassA {

   constructor(){
      ...
      this.place = [];
   }

   fillUp() {
      fetch(path)
        .then(function(response) {
          response.json()
        })
        .then((function(result) {
          this.place.push({"result":result})
        }).bind(this))
      }
    }
inst = new ClassA();   
inst.fillUp();
```

Comment: or the classic `var that = this;` before the promise starts.

Comment: @TKoL Yes, but as of ES6, that's not the best method. However, in pre-ES6 that was the only one...

Comment: Thanks - I rewrite the function with ES6  arrow notation and 'this' works now without  bind() or const that = this;

Comment: @TKoL Just a typo, I've meant to write pre-ES5, as `.bind()` was added in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then((result) => {
 this.place.push({"result":result})
})
```

works great. Than you!