# reCAPTCHA: Cannot combine methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I tried to integrate reCAPTCHA v3 to my Login form and applied all the necessary configuration combinations and examples. Here is my implementation based on [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge) page. However, I cannot pass the `g-recaptcha-response` value to my `Java` backend. I think the problem is related to combining `grecaptcha` and `submit` methods below.

***index.html:***

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
```

***login.vue:***

```
<a-button class="primary g-recaptcha" <!-- added "g-recaptcha" to the class -->
          @click="onSubmit">
          Login
</a-button>
```

```
onSubmit() {
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'})
                .then(function(token) {

        // I move my login block to here ---------------------------------
        this.$refs.formContainer.validate((valid) => { // --> throws error
        if (valid) {
            const params = { email: 'test@test.com', password: '******' };
            this.login(params).then((response) => {
              // pass "token" value to the backend
            });
          }
          return false;
        });
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------

      });
    });
  }
},
```

Although I get the token value properly, the `this.$refs.formContainer.validate((valid)` line throws "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined*" error. So, how should I combine these methods (`grecaptcha.execute` and my login block) properly?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it is because the scope of `this` changed. Take a look at the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises

Comment: @Marcel Thank you very much Marcel, yes the problem seems to be that. But it is really very interesting for `this` in JavaScript. Regards

Comment: On the other hand, how should I update the methods above?

Comment: I added an answer, does this solve it?