# typescript window.setInterval() not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues with the window.setInterval() method. Below is an example of the structure, the method "repeat" is called repeatedly, however I cannot call any methods inside "repeat". In the example when I instantiate manager (let m = new manager()) it will print "Before Print", but will not print out the log from the printStuff method, or the "After Print" message.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Obviously this isn't my actual code as it's simple enough to not be in separate functions, however my actual code needs to call many functions in the "repeat" function and it will stop execution when it finds a call to another function.

```
class manager{

constructor(){
    window.setInterval(this.repeat, 5000);
}

repeat(){
    console.log("Before Print");
    this.printStuff();
    console.log("After Print");
}

printStuff(){
    console.log("Print Stuff");
}
```

Comment: Try `setInterval(this.repeat.bind(this), 5000)` - Did you check the console for error messages? I'd expect something about `printStuff` being undefined, because the way you have it `this` isn't what you think it is...

Comment: This question has been asked a hundred times. Please search harder. You could off by reading up on how `this` works.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802436/why-does-method-on-object-loose-correct-this-binding-in-settimeout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set interval will take take the this.repeat out of the context you need to either explicitly 'bind' the method using

`setInterval(this.repeat.bind(this), 5000)`

or

`setInterval(()=>this.repeat(), 5000)`

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't take anything out of context. The context is lost the minute you say `this.repeat`.

Comment: not true the times, all of them, reassign the functions execution context thats why this does no mean the same unless you explicitly bind the functions

Comment: I cannot parse your comment. Nothing is being "re-assigned". The value `this.repeat` has no context to start with.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon—you can not "*reassign the functions execution context*", you have absolutely no control over that. Perhaps you just misused [*execution context*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts). ;-)

Comment: when you bind a function you are reassigning the context (this) in which is executed you can use implicit binding or explicit binding using bind, call or apply,  a few readings about it 
https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-basics-the-execution-context-and-the-lexical-environment-3505d4fe1be2
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2265-changing-the-execution-context-of-javascript-functions-using-call-and-apply.htm