# Understanding this and setTimeout in simple Example

Tags: javascript

In following example I have a couple of surprises:

> I am sad, people not even reading question properly before voting it down. **JSFiddle wraps variables to set them local**. Please, dont show it as a proof in this case! --- And, also someone who was **extra clever** removed my code and wrapped it in fiddle to show his Great Stupidity to next level!

**Snippet:**

```js
this.a = 100;
var a = 200;

function b() {
  this.a = 300;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.a)
  }, 0);
}
b();
console.log("Hello");
console.log(a);
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Query:**

> 1. When setTimeout is 0, the first log must be 300. Why do I see Hello printed before? (As function b is executed before "console.log(Hello)".
> 2. The 3rd log must have the value "200", as this.a in both lines refers to window.a as this refers to window object in both locations. variable a still hods value as 200.
> 3. While chrome shows Hello, 300, 300 Fiddle shows Hello, 200, 300

Any explanations for these 2 phenomenons?

> **Note: JSfiddle wraps the code in function to set them as local variables, so dont consider it for the current example. Try out in Chrome!**

Comment: It seems just impossible that `console.log(a);` would give you `300`

Comment: Try it out yourself. I too got goosebumps!

Comment: I did try it out, and I got `200` as expected. The answer to what you're asking, is that `setTimeout` defers execution until the thread is free, even when the timed delay is set to zero.

Comment: `this` is window so of course `window.a` will set `window.a`

Comment: Oh, okay, I tried it in a fiddle without global context, what @epascarello  said then, `this` is the window inside the function as well.

Comment: Yep, fiddle shows Hello, 200, 300 - Chrome shows Hello, 300, 300

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xppndngy/1/

Comment: be careful with `this` inside `setTimeout`

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript) might help

Comment: Within "fiddle" the global `this` isn't `window`. Don't take the behaviour of global stuff within a fiddle environment as canon, it's a very special environment.

Comment: Your whole problem is not being conscious of what `this` is and it's probably not what you think it is in each case. Start logging `this` for more clarity

Comment: @adeneo `console.log(a)` will give `300`. What is happening is OP is calling `b()`. This internally calls setTimeout. In it, OP updates `this.a` where `this` is pointing to `window`. Hence `300`

Comment: @Rajesh - thank you for the explanation, but I think I got it now.

Comment: Yep, Rajesh & @deceze- good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented,

> What is happening is OP is calling b(). This internally calls setTimeout. In it, OP updates `this.a` where `this` is pointing to window. Hence 300

Following is a sample where I have wrapped code in IIFE

```js
(function() {
  this.a = 100;
  var a = 200;

  function b() {
    this.a = 300;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.a)
    }, 0);
  }
  b();
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(a);
})()
```

#### Explanation

```js
// Here this points to window
this.a = 100;

// variables declared outside any functions are part of global scope (window)
var a = 200;

function b() {
  // this again points to window
  this.a = 300;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.a)
  }, 0);
}
b();
console.log("Hello");
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

> When setTimeout is 0, the first log must be 300. Why do I see Hello printed before? (As function b is executed before "console.log(Hello)".

No, all "timed out" function executions execute *asynchronously*. The execution is slotted into the next available time slot *after your current snippet has finished*. `0` simply schedules it very very soon, it doesn't make it a synchronous call.

> The 3rd log must have the value "200", as this.a in both lines refers to window.a as this refers to window object in both locations. variable a still hods value as 200.

This very much depends on what `this` is initially. When executed in a plain Javascript environment where the initial `this` is `window`, all `a`s refer to the same `window.a`, and the expected result is `300`, because that's what it's set to before it's being logged the first time.

> While chrome shows Hello, 300, 300 Fiddle shows Hello, 200, 300

The Fiddle environment is special and the initial `this` is not `window`.

Comment: @Peterson What's "GG"?

Comment: CS gamers will no `GG` as `Go Go`

Comment: @Peterson Never been to [Arkansas](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dota,+AR+72562/@35.7945186,-100.3427533,5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x87d3e4c65c12881b:0x8995ca56642824a2!8m2!3d35.7945204!4d-91.3779098?shorturl=1), ain't heard that dialect. 

Comment: Nopse, going to Moscow!

Comment: @Peterson Ah, sure, Дота, Moscow…