# why the value is undefine if there are in the same class ?

Tags: javascript

Im just trying to put a chronometer in html , but in the first 'if' of the method cronometro() the value of this.centesimas is undefine, and I really dont understand why because I declared these vars at the constructor of the class.

```
class NotaView {
  constructor () {
    this.centesimas = 0;
    this.segundos = 0;
    this.minutos = 0;
 }
  startCronometro() {
    this.control = setInterval(this.cronometro,10);


}

 cronometro () {

     this.Centesimas = document.getElementById("Centesimas");
     this.Segundos = document.getElementById("Segundos");
     this.Minutos = document.getElementById("Minutos");

     if (parseInt(this.centesimas) < 99) {
         parseInt(this.centesimas++);
        if (parseInt(this.centesimas) < 10) { this.centesimas = "0" + parseInt(this.centesimas) }
        this.Centesimas.innerHTML = ":" + parseInt(this.centesimas);
        console.log(this.centesimas)
    }
    if (parseInt(this.centesimas) == 99) {
        this.centesimas = -1;
    }
    if (parseInt(this.centesimas) == 0) {
        parseInt(this.segundos ++);
        if (parseInt(this.segundos) < 10) { this.segundos = "0" + parseInt(this.segundos )}
        this.Segundos.innerHTML = ":" + parseInt(this.segundos);
    }
    if (parseInt(this.segundos) == 59) {
        this.segundos = -1;
    }
    if ( (parseInt(this.centesimas) == 0)&&((this.segundos) == 0) ) {
        parseInt(this.minutos++);
        if (parseInt(this.minutos) < 10) { this.minutos = "0" + parseInt(this.minutos )}
        this.Minutos.innerHTML = ":" + parseInt(this.minutos);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout and "this" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you seen that you are using `this.centesimas` in `constuctor()` vs `this.Centesimas` in `cronometro ()`.  it could be the cappital letter 'C' the problem.

Comment: I know that are diferent , this.centesimas has the 0 value , and this.Centesimas is just a <div> inside html where i want to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this` is not determined when a function is created, it's determined by how the function is invoked. You're invoking the function directly as the callback of setInterval. This ends up invoking `chronometro` with `this` as the global object (or in strict mode `this` is undefined).

There are few options to fix this. If you can use Ecmascript 2015, i'd recommend creating an arrow function and calling this.cronometro inside it:

```
startCronometro() {
  this.control = setInterval(() => this.cronometro(), 10);
}
```

If you can't use ES2015, you can also use a regular function, but you'll need to manually save the value of `this`:

```
startCronometro() {
  var self = this;
  this.control = setInterval(function () {
    self.cronometro();
  }, 10);
}
```

Or you can create a bound version of the cronometro function:

```
startCronometro() {
  this.control = setInterval(this.cronometro.bind(this),10);
}
```

Comment: thanks that was a good solution , but now I have the next problem. When I instace the first object of NotaView the chronometer work well , but when when I instance the second object for have a result 2 different chronometes at the same time , just work on the first object and the second object just stay as 00:00:00 all the time. Any suggest able to have 2 different chronometes at the same time working ? sorry for my bad english :(