# Trying to start a loop in an instanced class/Object but tells me the loop method is not a function

Tags: javascript

Basically i start with this when document is ready:

```
var newObj = new MyClass(variables);
newObj.start();
```

And MyClass looks like this (simplying it here)

```
var MyClass = function(){

    this.start = function(){
         this.loop();
    }

    this.loop = function(){
        // do lots of stuff here
        setTimeout(function(){this.loop();}, 1000);
    }

} // end MyClass
```

During runtime it tells me that 'this.loop' is not a function  at the line where setTimeout is called

What am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback function to `this`?

Comment: Tl;Dr `this` in that setTimeout does not point to what you think it does. [The issue is that setTimeout() causes javascript to use the global scope. Essentially, you're calling the method() class, but not from "this". Instead you're just telling setTimeout to use the function "method", with no particular scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591343/542251)

Comment: Your problem is slightly different. Even without `setTimeout`, `(function(){this.loop();})();` wouldn't work. Every function call sets `this`.