# JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, function, closures, alias

I was just reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954417/make-alias-to-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript) and wanted to try the alias method rather than the function-wrapper method, but I couldn't seem to get it to work in either Firefox 3 or 3.5beta4, or Google Chrome, both in their debug windows and in a test web page.

Firebug:

```
>>> window.myAlias = document.getElementById
function()
>>> myAlias('item1')
>>> window.myAlias('item1')
>>> document.getElementById('item1')
<div id="item1">
```

If I put it in a web page, the call to myAlias gives me this error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object" nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)" location: "JS frame :: file:///[...snip...]/test.html :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 7" data: no]
```

Chrome (with >>>'s inserted for clarity):

```
>>> window.myAlias = document.getElementById
function getElementById() { [native code] }
>>> window.myAlias('item1')
TypeError: Illegal invocation
>>> document.getElementById('item1')
<div id=?"item1">?
```

And in the test page, I get the same "Illegal invocation".

Am I doing something wrong?  Can anyone else reproduce this?

Also, oddly enough, I just tried and it works in IE8.

Comment: in IE8 — it could be some kind of magic function or something.

Comment: I've added comments to the incorrect answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954417 and directed them here.

Comment: For browsers that support the Function.prototype.bind method: window.myAlias = document.getElementById.bind(document);

Search the MDN docs, there will be a bind shim.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to bind that method to the document object. Look:

```
>>> $ = document.getElementById
getElementById()
>>> $('bn_home')
[Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative" ... anonymous :: line 72 data: no]
>>> $.call(document, 'bn_home')
<body id="bn_home" onload="init();">
```

When you’re doing a simple alias, the function is called on the global object, not on the document object. Use a technique called closures to fix this:

```
function makeAlias(object, name) {
    var fn = object ? object[name] : null;
    if (typeof fn == 'undefined') return function () {}
    return function () {
        return fn.apply(object, arguments)
    }
}
$ = makeAlias(document, 'getElementById');

>>> $('bn_home')
<body id="bn_home" onload="init();">
```

This way you don’t loose the reference to the original object.

In 2012, there is the new `bind` method from ES5 that allows us to do this in a fancier way:

```
>>> $ = document.getElementById.bind(document)
>>> $('bn_home')
<body id="bn_home" onload="init();">
```

Comment: Which is really a wrapper because it returns a new function. I think the answer to Kev's question is that it is not possible for the reasons you describe above. The method you describe here is probably the best option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I hadn't looked closely enough to realize that.  So, the syntax in the answers on the other question is completely bogus?  Interesting...

Answer (score 194):

I dug deep to understand this particular behavior and I think I have found a good explanation.

Before I get in to why you are not able to alias `document.getElementById`, I will try to explain how JavaScript functions/objects work.

Whenever you invoke a JavaScript function, the JavaScript interpreter determines a scope and passes it to the function.

Consider following function:

```
function sum(a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}

sum(10, 20); // returns 30;
```

This function is declared in the Window scope and when you invoke it the value of `this` inside the sum function will be the global `Window` object.

For the 'sum' function, it doesn't matter what the value of 'this' is as it is not using it.

---

Consider following function:

```
function Person(birthDate)
{
    this.birthDate = birthDate;    
    this.getAge = function() { return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthDate.getFullYear(); };
}

var dave = new Person(new Date(1909, 1, 1)); 
dave.getAge(); //returns 100.
```

When you call dave.getAge function, the JavaScript interpreter sees that you are calling getAge function on the `dave` object, so it sets `this` to `dave` and calls the `getAge` function. `getAge()` will correctly return `100`.

---

You may know that in JavaScript you can specify the scope using the `apply` method. Let's try that.

```
var dave = new Person(new Date(1909, 1, 1)); //Age 100 in 2009
var bob = new Person(new Date(1809, 1, 1)); //Age 200 in 2009

dave.getAge.apply(bob); //returns 200.
```

In the above line, instead of letting JavaScript decide the scope, you are passing the scope manually as the `bob` object. `getAge` will now return `200` even though you 'thought' you called `getAge` on the `dave` object.

---

What's the point of all of the above? Functions are 'loosely' attached to your JavaScript objects. E.g. you can do

```
var dave = new Person(new Date(1909, 1, 1));
var bob = new Person(new Date(1809, 1, 1));

bob.getAge = function() { return -1; };

bob.getAge(); //returns -1
dave.getAge(); //returns 100
```

---

Let's take the next step.

```
var dave = new Person(new Date(1909, 1, 1));
var ageMethod = dave.getAge;

dave.getAge(); //returns 100;
ageMethod(); //returns ?????
```

`ageMethod` execution throws an error! What happened?

If you read my above points carefully, you would note that `dave.getAge` method was called with `dave` as `this` object whereas JavaScript could not determine the 'scope' for `ageMethod` execution. So it passed global 'Window' as 'this'. Now as `window` doesn't have a `birthDate` property, `ageMethod` execution will fail.

How to fix this? Simple,

```
ageMethod.apply(dave); //returns 100.
```

---

Did all of the above make sense? If it does, then you will be able to explain why you are not able to alias `document.getElementById`:

```
var $ = document.getElementById;

$('someElement');
```

`$` is called with `window` as `this` and if `getElementById` implementation is expecting `this` to be `document`, it will fail.

Again to fix this, you can do

```
$.apply(document, ['someElement']);
```

So why does it work in Internet Explorer?

I don't know the internal implementation of `getElementById` in IE, but a comment in jQuery source (`inArray` method implementation) says that in IE, `window == document`. If that's the case, then aliasing `document.getElementById` should work in IE.

To illustrate this further, I have created an elaborate example. Have a look at the `Person` function below.

```
function Person(birthDate)
{
    var self = this;

    this.birthDate = birthDate;

    this.getAge = function()
    {
        //Let's make sure that getAge method was invoked 
        //with an object which was constructed from our Person function.
        if(this.constructor == Person)
            return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthDate.getFullYear();
        else
            return -1;
    };

    //Smarter version of getAge function, it will always refer to the object
    //it was created with.
    this.getAgeSmarter = function()
    {
        return self.getAge();
    };

    //Smartest version of getAge function.
    //It will try to use the most appropriate scope.
    this.getAgeSmartest = function()
    {
        var scope = this.constructor == Person ? this : self;
        return scope.getAge();
    };

}
```

For the `Person` function above, here's how the various `getAge` methods will behave.

Let's create two objects using `Person` function.

```
var yogi = new Person(new Date(1909, 1,1)); //Age is 100
var anotherYogi = new Person(new Date(1809, 1, 1)); //Age is 200
```

---

```
console.log(yogi.getAge()); //Output: 100.
```

Straight forward, getAge method gets `yogi` object as `this` and outputs `100`.

---

```
var ageAlias = yogi.getAge;
console.log(ageAlias()); //Output: -1
```

JavaScript interepreter sets `window` object as `this` and our `getAge` method will return `-1`.

---

```
console.log(ageAlias.apply(yogi)); //Output: 100
```

If we set the correct scope, you can use `ageAlias` method.

---

```
console.log(ageAlias.apply(anotherYogi)); //Output: 200
```

If we pass in some other person object, it will still calculate age correctly.

```
var ageSmarterAlias = yogi.getAgeSmarter;    
console.log(ageSmarterAlias()); //Output: 100
```

The `ageSmarter` function captured the original `this` object so now you don't have to worry about supplying correct scope.

---

```
console.log(ageSmarterAlias.apply(anotherYogi)); //Output: 100 !!!
```

The problem with `ageSmarter` is that you can never set the scope to some other object.

---

```
var ageSmartestAlias = yogi.getAgeSmartest;
console.log(ageSmartestAlias()); //Output: 100
console.log(ageSmartestAlias.apply(document)); //Output: 100
```

The `ageSmartest` function will use the original scope if an invalid scope is supplied.

---

```
console.log(ageSmartestAlias.apply(anotherYogi)); //Output: 200
```

You will still be able to pass another `Person` object to `getAgeSmartest`. :)

Comment: +1 for why IE works.  The rest is a bit off-topic but still helpful in general.  :)

Comment: Excellent answer.  I don't see how any of it is off topic though.

Comment: Very nice answer, indeed. A somewhat shorter version is written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585840/implement-map-in-javascript-that-supports-object-methods-as-mapped-functions/585918#585918).

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen on stackoverflow.

Comment: why does it work in IE? because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994139/why-windowid-document-getelementbyid-id — so this method implementation may in fact be { return window[id] }, so it would work in any context

Comment: My passion for software engineering has been reignited after reading this

Answer (score 3):

This is a short answer.

The following makes a copy of (a reference to) the function. The problem is that now the function is on the `window` object when it was designed to live on the `document` object.

```
window.myAlias = document.getElementById
```

The alternatives are

- to use a wrapper (already mentioned by Fabien Ménager)
- or you can use two aliases.

  ```
  window.d = document // A renamed reference to the object
  window.d.myAlias = window.d.getElementById
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Another short answer, just for wrapping/aliasing `console.log` and similar logging methods. They all expect to be in the `console` context.

This is usable when wrapping `console.log` with some fallbacks, in case you or your users have run into trouble when [using a browser that doesn't (always) support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095348/website-with-js-doesnt-work-in-ie9-until-the-developer-tools-is-activated). This is not a full solution to that problem though, as it needs to be expanded checks and a fallback - your mileage may vary.

Example using warnings

```
var warn = function(){ console.warn.apply(console, arguments); }
```

Then use it as usual

```
warn("I need to debug a number and an object", 9999, { "user" : "Joel" });
```

If you prefer to see your logging arguments wrapped in an array (I do, most of the time), substitute [`.apply(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with [`.call(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Should work with `console.log()`, `console.debug()`, `console.info()`, `console.warn()`, `console.error()`. See also [`console` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console).

[console](/questions/tagged/console) [firebug](/questions/tagged/firebug)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other great answers, there's simple jQuery method [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

You can alias like this:

```
myAlias = $.proxy(document, 'getElementById');
```

Or

```
myAlias = $.proxy(document.getElementById, document);
```

Comment: +1 because it's a feasible solution. But, strictly speaking, behind the scenes `$.proxy` is also a wrapper really.

Answer (score -6):

You actually *can't* "pure alias" a function on a predefined object.  Therefore, the closest to aliasing you can get without wrapping is by staying within the same object:

```
>>> document.s = document.getElementById;
>>> document.s('myid');
<div id="myid">
```

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. You can 'pure alias' a function provided that the function implementation's use of 'this'. So it depends.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the context of getElementById.  You're right.  I've changed the answer slightly to reflect this...