# JavaScript Infinitely Looping slideshow with delays?

Tags: javascript, loops

How do I make an infinite loop in JavaScript? I'm trying to make a slideshow, which I have working, but I can't get it to loop. I can't even get it to loop twice.

The code I'm using right now is

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}
function slide() {
    var num = 0;
    for (num=0;num<=10;num++) {
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-600px'",3000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1200px'",6000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1800px'",9000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='0px'",12000);
    }
}
```

Without the for thing in there, it does go through once. When I put in a for, it either makes Firefox lock up, or just loops once. I'm sure this is a really simple thing to do, and even if it has to be loop 1,000,000 times or something instead of infinite, that'd work fine for me.

Also, I don't want to use jQuery or something that someone else created. I'm learning JavaScript, and this is partially to help me learn, and partially because I'm trying to make as many HTML5-based systems as I can.

EDIT: I think the reason it's freezing is because it executes the code all at once, and then just stores it in a cache or something. What I want it to do is go through this once, then start at the top again, which is what I've always thought loops where for. In "batch" (command prompt) scripting, this could be done with a "`GOTO`" command. I don't know if there's an equivalent in JS or not, but that's really my goal.

Comment: What does not using jQuery have to do with using HTML5?

Comment: jQuery doesn't keep you from learning Javascript. It's there to help hide the (far far far too many) differences in every browser's javascript implementations. Believe me, you'll still get your hands very dirty with Javascript, even with jquery's help.

Comment: Oh, and most browsers don't let you run an infinite loop in javascript. It'd be far too easy to do DoS attacks on people if they did. After a certain time/number of operations, they'll pop up warning dialogues that the script may be misbehaving and let the user abort the script.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The correct approach is to use a single timer.  Using `setInterval`, you can achieve what you want as follows:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}
function slide() {
    var num = 0, style = document.getElementById('container').style;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        // increase by num 1, reset to 0 at 4
        num = (num + 1) % 4;

        // -600 * 1 = -600, -600 * 2 = -1200, etc 
        style.marginLeft = (-600 * num) + "px"; 
    }, 3000); // repeat forever, polling every 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you :) This was actually what I was trying to do originally, but couldn't figure out how to add to the marginLeft. EDIT: This answer is EXACTLY what I wanted, too, because it just requires one quick edit if I want to add like 20 slides. Thank you, this is great.

Comment: @Rev: happy to help, there were a lot of confusing answers here so I thought it would be a good idea to toss in my solution :-)

Comment: @Andy This looks similar to mine, with the major exception being (I think) that yours is written fancier :)

Comment: @josh: you're right, it is similar. There were so many answers here, I didn't notice yours when wrote mine.  +1 for your answer :-)

Comment: @Andy I don't blame you, I myself kept thinking I had to be missing an answer (like ours) in the mess of answers provided. I looked over the pile quite a few times thinking I had missed it, but realized that in actuality, almost every answer was wrong. I do see you chose the `setInterval` route though, so your answer IS different :)

Comment: Awesome.  I felt like playing with this a bit, so added a little to it: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/fy3vQ/

Comment: @entropo: That's pretty neat :-)

Comment: The window.onload function does nothing but invoke another function.  window.onload = slide; will do.

Comment: When doing animations (with an interval less than 1000 ms), you should use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) since it optimizes the updating of the screen.

Answer (score 20):

You don't want `while(true)`, that will lock up your system.

What you want instead is a timeout that sets a timeout on itself, something like this:

```
function start() {
  // your code here
  setTimeout(start, 3000);
}

// boot up the first call
start();
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a nice, tidy solution for you: ([also see the live demo ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/QLW6E/))

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}

function slide() {
    var currMarg = 0,
        contStyle = document.getElementById('container').style;
    setInterval(function() {
        currMarg = currMarg == 1800 ? 0 : currMarg + 600;
        contStyle.marginLeft = '-' + currMarg + 'px';
    }, 3000);
}
```

Since you are trying to learn, allow me to explain how this works.

First we declare two variables: `currMarg` and `contStyle`.  `currMarg` is an integer that we will use to track/update what left margin the container should have.  We declare it outside the actual update function (in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)), so that it can be continuously updated/access without losing its value.  `contStyle` is simply a convenience variable that gives us access to the containers styles without having to locate the element on each interval.

Next, we will use `setInterval` to establish a function which should be called every 3 seconds, until we tell it to stop (there's your infinite loop, without freezing the browser).  It works exactly like `setTimeout`, except it happens infinitely until cancelled, instead of just happening once.

We pass an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work) to `setInterval`, which will do our work for us.  The first line is:

```
currMarg = currMarg == 1800 ? 0 : currMarg + 600;
```

This is a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). It will assign `currMarg` the value of `0` if `currMarg` is equal to `1800`, otherwise it will increment `currMarg` by `600`.

With the second line, we simply assign our chosen value to `container`s marginLeft, and we're done!

Note: For the demo, I changed the negative values to positive, so the effect would be visible.

Comment: Pip pip! What say we celebrate our good health over a pipe of the finest tabac my good chap?

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://pastebin.com/kB2FDp1B) and consider making a revision.

Comment: Also, with ES2015's improvements to JavaScript, it is now possible to write a simple format function in one line: https://pastebin.com/b1nVqKZZ

Comment: You know, upon actually reading your implementation, I notice some hard-coding that still needs to be addressed. See [this addendum](https://pastebin.com/TEQGCaCL). I'll probably just end up writing my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhps this is what you are looking for.

```
var pos = 0;
window.onload = function start() {
    setTimeout(slide, 3000);
}
function slide() {
   pos -= 600;
   if (pos === -2400)
     pos = 0;
   document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft= pos + "px";
   setTimeout(slide, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Using setTimeout in this way is equivalent to [using a GOTO](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `setTimeout()` ten times in a row, so they all expire almost at the same time. What you actually want is this:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide(10);
}
function slide(repeats) {
    if (repeats > 0) {
        document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-600px';
        document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1200px';
        document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1800px';
        document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='0px';
        window.setTimeout(
          function(){
            slide(repeats - 1)
          },
          3000
        );
    }
}
```

This will call slide(10), which will then set the 3-second timeout to call slide(9), which will set timeout to call slide(8), etc. When slide(0) is called, no more timeouts will be set up.

Comment: This defeats the point of a sliding photo show - you are not leaving the container in place for any length of time before moving it back to its origin!

Answer (score 1):

You can infinitely loop easily enough via recursion.

```
function it_keeps_going_and_going_and_going() {
  it_keeps_going_and_going_and_going();
}

it_keeps_going_and_going_and_going()
```

Comment: This isn't infinite, but will instead crash after a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The key is not to schedule all pics at once, but to schedule a next pic each time you have a pic shown.

```
var current = 0;
var num_slides = 10;
function slide() {
    // here display the current slide, then:

    current = (current + 1) % num_slides;
    setTimeout(slide, 3000);
}
```

The alternative is to use `setInterval`, which sets the function to repeat regularly (as opposed to `setTimeout`, which schedules the next appearance only.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Ender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835533/1175714), let's explore our options with the improvements from ES2015.

---

First off, the problem in the asker's code is the fact that `setTimeout` is asynchronous while *loops* are synchronous. So the logical flaw is that they wrote multiple calls to an asynchronous function from a synchronous loop, expecting them to execute synchronously.

```
function slide() {
    var num = 0;
    for (num=0;num<=10;num++) {
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-600px'",3000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1200px'",6000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1800px'",9000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='0px'",12000);
    }
}
```

What happens in reality, though, is that...

- The loop "simultaneously" creates 44 async timeouts set to execute 3, 6, 9 and 12 seconds in the future. Asker expected the 44 calls to execute one-after-the-other, but instead, they all execute simultaneously.
- 3 seconds after the loop finishes, `container`'s marginLeft is set to `"-600px"` 11 times.
- 3 seconds after that, marginLeft is set to `"-1200px"` 11 times.
- 3 seconds later, `"-1800px"`, 11 times.

And so on.

You could solve this by changing it to:

```
function setMargin(margin){
    return function(){
        document.querySelector("#container").style.marginLeft = margin;
    };
}

function slide() {
    for (let num = 0; num <= 10; ++num) {
        setTimeout(setMargin("-600px"), + (3000 * (num + 1)));
        setTimeout(setMargin("-1200px"), + (6000 * (num + 1)));
        setTimeout(setMargin("-1800px"), + (9000 * (num + 1)));
        setTimeout(setMargin("0px"), + (12000 * (num + 1)));
    }
}
```

But that is just a lazy solution that doesn't address the other issues with this implementation. There's a lot of hardcoding and general sloppiness here that ought to be fixed.

### Lessons learnt from a decade of experience

As mentioned at the top of this answer, Ender already proposed a solution, but I would like to add on to it, to factor in good practice and modern innovations in the ECMAScript specification.

```
function format(str, ...args){
    return str.split(/(%)/).map(part => (part == "%") ? (args.shift()) : (part)).join("");
}

function slideLoop(margin, selector){
    const multiplier = -600;
    let contStyle = document.querySelector(selector).style;

    return function(){
        margin = ++margin % 4;
        contStyle.marginLeft = format("%px", margin * multiplier);
    }
}

function slide() {    
    return setInterval(slideLoop(0, "#container"), 3000);
}
```

Let's go over how this works for the total beginners (note that not all of this is directly related to the question):

### format

```
function format
```

It's immensely useful to have a printf-like string formatter function in *any* language. I don't understand why JavaScript doesn't seem to have one.

```
format(str, ...args)
```

`...` is a snazzy feature added in ES6 that lets you do lots of stuff. I believe it's called the spread operator. Syntax: `...identifier` or `...array`. In a function header, you can use it to specify variable arguments, and it will take every argument at and past the position of said variable argument, and stuff them into an array. You can also call a function with an array like so: `args = [1, 2, 3]; i_take_3_args(...args)`, or you can take an array-like object and transform it into an array: `...document.querySelectorAll("div.someclass").forEach(...)`. This would not be possible without the spread operator, because `querySelectorAll` returns an "element list", which isn't a true array.

```
str.split(/(%)/)
```

I'm not good at explaining how regex works. JavaScript has two syntaxes for regex. There's the OO way (`new RegExp("regex", "gi")`) and there's the literal way (`/insert regex here/gi`). I have a profound hatred for regex because the terse syntax it encourages often does more harm than good (and also because they're extremely non-portable), but there are some instances where regex is helpful, like this one. Normally, if you called split with `"%"` or `/%/`, the resulting array would exclude the "%" delimiters from the array. But for the algorithm used here, we need them included. `/(%)/` was the first thing I tried and it worked. Lucky guess, I suppose.

```
.map(...)
```

`map` is a functional idiom. You use map to apply a function to a list. Syntax: `array.map(function)`. Function: must return a value and take 1-2 arguments. The first argument will be used to hold each value in the array, while the second will be used to hold the current index in the array. Example: `[1,2,3,4,5].map(x => x * x); // returns [1,4,9,16,25]`. See also: filter, find, reduce, forEach.

```
part => ...
```

This is an alternative form of function. Syntax: `argument-list => return-value`, e.g. `(x, y) => (y * width + x)`, which is equivalent to `function(x, y){return (y * width + x);}`.

```
(part == "%") ? (args.shift()) : (part)
```

The `?:` operator pair is a 3-operand operator called the ternary conditional operator. Syntax: `condition ? if-true : if-false`, although most people call it the "ternary" operator, since in every language it appears in, it's the only 3-operand operator, every other operator is binary (+, &&, |, =) or unary (++, ..., &, *). Fun fact: some languages (and vendor extensions of languages, like GNU C) implement a two-operand version of the `?:` operator with syntax `value ?: fallback`, which is equivalent to `value ? value : fallback`, and will use `fallback` if `value` evaluates to false. They call it the Elvis Operator.

I should also mention the difference between an `expression` and an `expression-statement`, as I realize this may not be intuitive to all programmers. An `expression` represents a value, and can be assigned to an `l-value`. An expression can be stuffed inside parentheses and not be considered a syntax error. An expression can itself be an `l-value`, although most statements are `r-values`, as the only l-value expressions are those formed from an identifier or (e.g. in C) from a reference/pointer. Functions can return l-values, but don't count on it. Expressions can also be compounded from other, smaller expressions. `(1, 2, 3)` is an expression formed from three r-value expressions joined by two comma operators. The value of the expression is 3. `expression-statements`, on the other hand, are statements formed from a single expression. `++somevar` is an expression, as it can be used as the r-value in the assignment expression-statement `newvar = ++somevar;` (the value of the expression `newvar = ++somevar`, for example, is the value that gets assigned to `newvar`). `++somevar;` is also an expression-statement.

If ternary operators confuse you at all, apply what I just said to the ternary operator: `expression ? expression : expression`. Ternary operator can form an expression or an expression-statement, so both of these things:

```
smallest = (a < b) ? (a) : (b);
(valueA < valueB) ? (backup_database()) : (nuke_atlantic_ocean());
```

are valid uses of the operator. Please don't do the latter, though. That's what `if` is for. There are cases for this sort of thing in e.g. C preprocessor macros, but we're talking about JavaScript here.

```
args.shift()
```

`Array.prototype.shift`. It's the mirror version of `pop`, ostensibly inherited from shell languages where you can call `shift` to move onto the next argument. `shift` "pops" the first argument out of the array and returns it, mutating the array in the process. The inverse is `unshift`. Full list:

```
array.shift()
    [1,2,3] -> [2,3], returns 1
array.unshift(new-element)
    [element, ...] -> [new-element, element, ...]
array.pop()
    [1,2,3] -> [1,2], returns 3
array.push(new-element)
    [..., element] -> [..., element, new-element]
```

See also: slice, splice

```
.join("")
```

`Array.prototype.join(string)`. This function turns an array into a string. Example: `[1,2,3].join(", ") -> "1, 2, 3"`

### slide

```
return setInterval(slideLoop(0, "#container"), 3000);
```

First off, we return `setInterval`'s return value so that it may be used later in a call to `clearInterval`. This is important, because JavaScript won't clean that up by itself. I strongly advise against using `setTimeout` to make a loop. That is not what `setTimeout` is designed for, and by doing that, you're reverting to GOTO. Read Dijkstra's 1968 paper, *Go To Statement Considered Harmful,* to understand why GOTO loops are bad practice.

Second off, you'll notice I did some things differently. The repeating interval is the obvious one. This will run forever until the interval is cleared, and at a delay of 3000ms. The value for the *callback* is the return value of another function, which I have fed the arguments `0` and `"#container"`. This creates a closure, and you will understand how this works shortly.

### slideLoop

```
function slideLoop(margin, selector)
```

We take margin (0) and selector ("#container") as arguments. The margin is the initial margin value and the selector is the CSS selector used to find the element we're modifying. Pretty straightforward.

```
const multiplier = -600;
let contStyle = document.querySelector(selector).style;
```

I've moved some of the hard coded elements up. Since the margins are in multiples of -600, we have a clearly labeled constant multiplier with that base value.

I've also created a reference to the element's *style* property via the CSS selector. Since `style` is an object, this is safe to do, as it will be treated as a *reference* rather than a *copy* (read up on *Pass By Sharing* to understand these semantics).

```
return function(){
    margin = ++margin % 4;
    contStyle.marginLeft = format("%px", margin * multiplier);
}
```

Now that we have the scope defined, we return a function that uses said scope. This is called a closure. You should read up on those, too. Understanding JavaScript's admittedly bizarre scoping rules will make the language a lot less painful in the long run.

```
margin = ++margin % 4;
contStyle.marginLeft = format("%px", margin * multiplier);
```

Here, we simply increment margin and modulus it by 4. The sequence of values this will produce is `1->2->3->0->1->...`, which mimics exactly the behavior from the question without any complicated or hard-coded logic.

Afterwards, we use the `format` function defined earlier to painlessly set the marginLeft CSS property of the container. It's set to the currnent margin value multiplied by the multiplier, which as you recall was set to -600. `-600 -> -1200 -> -1800 -> 0 -> -600 -> ...`

---

There are some important differences between my version and Ender's, which I mentioned in [a comment](https://pastebin.com/kB2FDp1B) on their answer. I'm gonna go over the reasoning now:

> Use `document.querySelector(css_selector)` instead of `document.getElementById(id)`

querySelector was added in ES6, if I'm not mistaken. querySelector (returns first found element) and querySelectorAll (returns a list of all found elements) are part of the prototype chain of *all* DOM elements (not just `document`), and take a CSS selector, so there are other ways to find an element than just by its ID. You can search by ID (`#idname`), class (`.classname`), relationships (`div.container div div span`, `p:nth-child(even)`), and attributes (`div[name]`, `a[href=https://google.com]`), among other things.

> Always track `setInterval(fn, interval)`'s return value so it can later be closed with `clearInterval(interval_id)`

It's not good design to leave an interval running forever. It's also not good design to write a function that calls itself via `setTimeout`. That is no different from a GOTO loop. The return value of `setInterval` should be stored and used to clear the interval when it's no longer needed. Think of it as a form of memory management.

> Put the interval's callback into its own formal function for readability and maintainability

Constructs like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    ...
}, 1000);
```

Can get clunky pretty easily, especially if you are storing the return value of setInterval. I strongly recommend putting the function outside of the call and giving it a name so that it's clear and self-documenting. This also makes it possible to call a function that returns an anonymous function, in case you're doing stuff with closures (a special type of object that contains the local state surrounding a function).

`Array.prototype.forEach` is fine.

> If state is kept with the callback, the callback should be returned from another function (e.g. `slideLoop`) to form a closure

You don't want to mush state and callbacks together the way Ender did. This is mess-prone and can become hard to maintain. The state should be in the same function that the anonymous function comes from, so as to clearly separate it from the rest of the world. A better name for `slideLoop` could be `makeSlideLoop`, just to make it extra clear.

> Use proper whitespace. Logical blocks that do different things should be separated by one empty line

This:

```
print(some_string);

if(foo && bar)
    baz();

while((some_number = some_fn()) !== SOME_SENTINEL && ++counter < limit)
    ;

quux();
```

is much easier to read than this:

```
print(some_string);
if(foo&&bar)baz();
while((some_number=some_fn())!==SOME_SENTINEL&&++counter<limit);
quux();
```

A lot of beginners do this. Including little 14-year-old me from 2009, and I didn't unlearn that bad habit until probably 2013. Stop trying to crush your code down so small.

> Avoid `"string" + value + "string" + ...`. Make a format function or use `String.prototype.replace(string/regex, new_string)`

Again, this is a matter of readability. This:

```
format("Hello %! You've visited % times today. Your score is %/% (%%).",
    name, visits, score, maxScore, score/maxScore * 100, "%"
);
```

is much easier to read than this horrific monstrosity:

```
"Hello " + name + "! You've visited " + visits + "% times today. " + 
"Your score is " + score + "/" + maxScore + " (" + (score/maxScore * 100) +
"%).",
```

edit: I'm pleased to point out that I made in error in the above snippet, which in my opinion is a great demonstration of how error-prone this method of string building is.

```
visits + "% times today"
          ^ whoops
```

It's a good demonstration because the entire reason I made that error, and didn't notice it for as long as I did(n't), is because the code is bloody hard to read.

> Always surround the arguments of your ternary expressions with parens. It aids readability and prevents bugs.

I borrow this rule from the best practices surrounding C preprocessor macros. But I don't really need to explain this one; see for yourself:

```
let myValue = someValue < maxValue ? someValue * 2 : 0;
let myValue = (someValue < maxValue) ? (someValue * 2) : (0);
```

I don't care how well you think you understand your language's syntax, the latter will ALWAYS be easier to read than the former, and readability is the the only argument that is necessary. You read thousands of times more code than you write. Don't be a jerk to your future self long-term just so you can pat yourself on the back for being clever in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}
function slide() {
    var num = 0;
    for (num=0;num==10;) {
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-600px'",3000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1200px'",6000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1800px'",9000);
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='0px'",12000);
    }
}
```

That makes it keep looping alright! That's why it isn't runnable here.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}
function slide() {
     setInterval("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-600px'",3000);
     setInterval("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1200px'",6000);
     setInterval("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='-1800px'",9000);
     setInterval("document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft='0px'",12000);
}
```

`setInterval` is basically an 'infinite loop' and it wont black up the browser. it waits the required time, then goes again

Comment: That will cause the interval callbacks to overlap each other and result in an undesirable effect.

Comment: @andy thats better than many many setTimeouts overlapping 10X

Comment: @Neal: the original setTimeouts don't overlap - they are sequential at 3000, 6000, 9000 etc.  With your approach, the first timer will fire at 3000... 6000... 9000... when it should fire at 3000... 15000... 27000... etc

Comment: @Andy, your arguement makes no sense

Comment: @Andy see the end of @Oded's answer

Comment: @Neal: it makes perfect sense if you look at your solution and compare it to the OP's approach.  The fact that Oded edited the same approach into his answer doesn't make it any less fail.

Answer (score -1):

you can use requestAnimationFrame() function like in the below,

```
function unlimited () {
    requestAnimationFrame(unlimited);
    console.log("arian")
}

unlimited();
```