# Infinite Loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, infinite

I have an animation of a car driving back and forth across the screen and have figured out how to flip the image when it reaches the right side of the screen and then again when it reaches the left side. However, I need to loop this JS event so the animation constantly shows the car driving in the correct 'direction.' The code below should give you an idea of what I'm working with, so if anyone could be so kind as to help this beginner figure out how to make it loop infinitely, I would greatly appreciate it.

*tl/dr

Basically I need the code below to loop infinitely.

```
var carorange = $('.org-car');
    setTimeout(function () {
        carorange.addClass('flipimg');
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        carorange.removeClass('flipimg');
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Infinite Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`:

```
var carorange = $('.org-car');
setInterval(function () {
    carorange.toggleClass('flipimg');
}, 5000);
```

`setInterval` has a nother big advantage: You can stop the interval. So if you assign the interval to a variable, like `var myTimer = setInterval...`, you can stop it at any time using `clearInterval(myTimer);` :)

Comment: Nit: setTimeout can be cancelled too, so it's not a "big advantage" for setInterval (and canceling is not necessarily any easier than not restarting or immediately terminating in the callback). setInterval does has a slight "re-prime" advantage/difference in terms of when the next tick is scheduled, but it's it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/729943/2246674

Comment: Using two intervals isn't a good idea. They'll likely get out of sync after a while. Just use one `5000` millisecond interval, and toggle the class.

Comment: Crazy Train is totally right. I just wanted to help quickly! ;) I edited the answer.

Comment: you're all a bunch of wizards. works like a charm! thanks everyone!