# Trying a infinite loop on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I am trying to do a infinite loop, but it only works if I include an 'alert' on it. My code looks like this:

```
while( tocontinue ){
  // Some code
  alert('Accept to continue');
}
```

On this way, the user has to click to hide the alerts (for example, on Chrome), and then the loop continues correctly by itself. I need to implement this without any alert. I also tried this:

```
while( tocontinue ){
  // Some code
  tocontinue = false;
  setTimeout(function(){tocontinue=true},500);
}
```

And with "window.setTimeout" too, and without the word "function(){}", but it doesn't work. I tried everything: some implementations on JavaScript of a sleep() function, calling the function each *X* time with setInterval, answers 1 and 3 on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop)... :/

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can implement infinite loop by `while (true)`

Comment: Asynchronous tasks, like timers, cannot complete until the execution thread is idle, which a `while (true)` will never let it be.

Comment: I doubt the first example is working. [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) is reserved.

Comment: @RoyMiloh I think `continue` here is actually the name of a boolean variable OP is using.. Though I didn't think that was possible..

Comment: [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue), do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: @jonhopkins It really isn't possible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you give us an better idea of what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to actually help you.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed "continue" to "tocontinue" (I was using really a spanish variable name, so I had this mistake on translation, sorry). I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm, and I want to stop it when I decide (with a button that puts the global variable "tocontinue" to false). Meanwhile, I want a infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm, and I want to stop it when I decide (with a button that puts the global variable "tocontinue" to false). Meanwhile, I want a infinite loop.

Well, you won't be able to combine a true infinite loop with user interaction as they'll both be dependent on the same thread being able to work on them exclusively. But, you can get close with a near-instant interval.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    // some code
}, 10);
```

Possibly grouping a few iterations together for each round:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var limit = 5;
    while (limit--) {
        // some code
    }
}, 10);
```

But, the interval will keep the iteration going as quickly as possible while still giving some idle time for user interactions, like clicking a particular button to [clear the interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval).

```
document.getElementById('stopButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, false);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/xZBTF/

Comment: Thank you very much, Jonathan! There are so many options when you are not sure... I tried setTimeout with and without "function()" word, but not with setInterval. Sorry for my inexperience... Your solution is really elegant, and works very fine.

Answer (score 3):

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) may be more useful here.

```
function updateLoop() {
   //All the code goes here 
}

setInterval(updateLoop,500);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, with or without brackets :( I said I already tried it.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what more I can do without seeing the source code.

Comment: Yes, I put the content of my while on a new function called "updateLoop", and I called it from a setInterval function, just how Daniel suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {

    reader.open('get', 'ccc.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {

if(reader.readyState==4) {

var el = document.getElementById('main');

el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;

var data =  el.innerHTML;


 }

   }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for(var I = 7; I >1; i+=3);
console.log(i)
```