# how do I create an infinite loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

I want to create an infinite loop in JavaScript.

What are some ways to achieve this:

eg

```
for (var i=0; i<Infinity; i++) {}
```

Comment: `while(1){}` works in almost all programming languages.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop ... even though the titles are similar

Answer (score 80):

You can also use a while loop:

```js
while (true) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Won't this throw an exception?

Comment: This will block the Javascript execution in the page, leading to a browser dialog asking to stop or debug the script. It won't work

Comment: @Alberto Except if you are not programming for browsers

Comment: @Alberto It's absolutely ok inside generator functions.

Comment: In a case, if it is expected to execute in a browser, a better way to implement an infinite loop Is using setTimeout or setInterval function. This post contains more descriptive details about that. (https://nextcsguide.com/javascript/javascript-infinite-loops-that-work-on-browsers/)

Answer (score 77):

By omitting all parts of the head, the loop can also become infinite:

```
for (;;) {}
```

Comment: That is better than while(true){}: if you use ESLint, it won't trigger http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition.

Comment: For some reason, I just hate how this looks in my code. So cryptic. I wonder if there's a more semantic way to do it? But yeah, seems like the way to go in this case!

Comment: This one seems a better choice, since some code optimizers (like Webpack Terser plugin) spam with warnings like `Condition always false` and `Dropping unreachable code` when using the `while (true)` variant.

Comment: You can break `for(;;) {}` loops with `true` between the semicolons `for(;true;) { if(condition) break; //do work }`.

Comment: I like it just because it's unique :D