# Javascript code is wrong i don't know why

Tags: javascript

why can't this code work ? I'm trying to change an image every 4 seconds...
I really don't understand, everything should work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Falcon0408()
{
document.getElementByTagName('img');


if (document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img1.png')
{
document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img2.png';
}




else if (document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img2.png')
{
document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img3.png';

}

else if (document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img3')
{
document.getElementByTagName('img').src='img1.png';
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
setTimeout(Falcon0408(),400);
</script>
<img src='img.png'/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(Falcon0408,400);` <-- don't invoke the function, `setTimeout` expects a function reference

Comment: for starters, `getElementByTagName` does not exist, and `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

Comment: Also src is 'img.png' which isn't 'img1.png', 'img2.png' or 'img3'.

Comment: Anyways, invoking setTimeout only once will only invoke the function once.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's `getElementsByTagName` - "elements" is plural because you get all of the ones with that tag.
2. You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of comparison `==` or `===`.
3. The actual image source in the HTML is just "img.png" so it will never match any of your "if" statements.
4. Not an error, but a tip: "Don't Repeat Yourself." Get the image's attribute once, and store it in a variable, then check against that variable.
5. Give your image tag a unique ID so you can target it directly with `getElementById` (note it's "Id" not "ID"). What if you have multiple `img` tags on the page? You probably don't want all of them to change.

Code:

```
<img id="myImg" src="img1.png"/>

function Falcon0408()
{
    var image = document.getElementById('myImg');

    if (image.src === 'img1.png')
   {
       image.src = 'img2.png';
   }

   else if (image.src === 'img2.png')
   {
       image.src='img3.png';
   }

   else if (image.src === 'img3')
   {
      image.src='img1.png';
   }
}
```

6. What will you do when you want to cycle through 20 or 1000 images? Will you keep adding if/else blocks?

A better approach would be to have an array of images (or just know exactly how many photos you have in the folder) and use a loop to change the source based on the number of images in the array. That way you don't have to keep adding else/if statements every time you want to add a new image ... but that's beyond the scope of this question.

7. If you want this to loop, this won't work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop) for how to use `setInterval()`, or how to include another call to setTimeout() inside the function so that it keeps going.

Comment: Good and thorough answer.

Comment: Added comment re: timeout issue - thanks for catching the other error too btw :)